# How can I perform static code analysis in PHP?

Tags: php, code-analysis, static-analysis

Is there a static analysis tool for PHP source files?

The binary itself can check for syntax errors, but I'm looking for something that does more, like:

- unused variable assignments
- arrays that are assigned into without being initialized first
- and possibly code style warnings
- ...

Comment: Related website: [The PHP Quality Assurance Toolchain (phpqatools.org)](http://phpqatools.org/) and another static tool is [PHP_CompatInfo](http://bartlett.laurent-laville.org/).

Comment: Righty-o: closed by SO, when clearly this kind of answer is incredibly useful.

Comment: agree. This question is crucial. php lint (php -l file) fails to provide the other half: run the autoload, make sure a function called exists, that variables exists, object properties exist. etc.

Comment: Phan (for php-7) has [just been released](https://github.com/etsy/phan).

Comment: @IraBaxter useful, but not, strictly speaking, on topic. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is probably a more on-topic location. Of course the irony here is that many more developers are familiar with SO than it's sibling...

Comment: The fact that so many people find this type of question useful is probably why softwarerecs now exists.  It certainly seemed on topic back when this was the only stack exchange site.  Now that there's a clear place for it, does it make sense to migrate?

Comment: Closed due to trigger-happy closers. Bah!

Comment: Neither being popular nor being old exempts a question from the rules. Nor are we "trigger happy"; there is no doubt that this question is asking for a library, nor that that kind of question is categorically off-topic. You are simply declaring "this question is *special* and so should be treated differently" without providing any actual reason your question merits such special treatment.

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Run `php` in lint mode from the command line to validate syntax without execution:

`php -l FILENAME`

Higher-level static analyzers include:

- [php-sat](http://www.program-transformation.org/PHP/PhpSat) - Requires http://strategoxt.org/
- [PHP_Depend](http://pdepend.org/)
- [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer)
- [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/)
- [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan)
- [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)
- [phan](https://github.com/phan/phan)

Lower-level analyzers include:

- [PHP_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser)
- [token_get_all](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) (primitive function)

Runtime analyzers, which are more useful for some things due to PHP's dynamic nature, include:

- [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) has [code coverage](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage) and [function traces](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace).
- My [PHP Tracer Tool](http://github.com/troelskn/php-tracer-weaver/tree/master) uses a combined static/dynamic approach, building on Xdebug's function traces.

The documentation libraries [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) and [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) perform a kind of code analysis. Doxygen, for example, can be configured to render nice inheritance graphs with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Another option is [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof), which is similar to Xdebug, but lighter, making it suitable for production servers. The tool includes a PHP-based interface.

Comment: PHP_CodeSniffer is easy to install and easy to use. :)

Comment: I know this is an answered question, but still, using `php -l` like this: `find /your/path -name '*.php' | xargs -r php -l` is not working reliably. It often misses files with syntax errors in them.

Comment: PHP_CodeSniffer looked very nice to me at the start, but I couldn't for the life of me make it NOT show indentations "errors". It seems it ignores the `--error-severity` option entirely.

Comment: +1 for taking 6 hours of my life in trying all these goodies!

Comment: @dimitko: That's because `php -l` can only read one input file at a time (that is, it won't work if you do `php -l file1.php file2.php`).  Instead you need to use the `-n 1` option, which tells `xargs` to only use one input line per command process.  That will instead cause it to run `php -l file1.php` followed by `php -l file2.php`, separately.  At the same time, you can use `-P <n>` to run "n" processes at a time, in order to parallelize the execution: `find . -name '*.inc' -o -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P10 php -l`

Comment: xdebug and xhprof are not static analysis tools.

Comment: @ira I *did* preface their mention by calling them "runtime analysis options", but perhaps I should have been more explicit?

Comment: `find /your/path -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \;` works reliable.

Comment: If you load a lot of extensions in your standard php.ini it can speed things up if you use `php -n -l filename.php` to make it use built-in defaults for ini settings when running checks on a large set of files.

Comment: **NB**: For the built-in lint function (`php -l`) to work, you must set `display_errors = on` in `php.ini`, otherwise you will only get a generic message about there being syntax errors but no details about what error(s) or what line(s).

Comment: Synetech - Good one. You could override the setting on the command line though, using the `-d` switch. E.g. `php -l -d display_errors=on $FILENAME`

Comment: @dimitko, I concur with your assessment of PHP_CodeSniffer. With one addition. It was very good at finding all my indentation errors (or so it thought, I disagreed in most cases) but it actually failed to spot the actual errors I inserted into my code to test it.

Comment: I also like [SensioLab's Coding Standards Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/).  This compares against [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).  What's nice is that it can automatically fix files for you (but if you just want it to list failing files, use its `--dry-run` option).

Comment: so, the best way to scan dir with code  using 8 processes is something like this - `find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 php -l`

Comment: SonarQube, and SonarLint plugin makes everything easy peazy

Comment: Is there a way to make SO reopen this question? The answers are wildly outdated information.

Comment: Sorry for necroposting, but for purpose of checking syntax errors on CI/CD in automation it is essential to have command status code on exit to be non-zero when testing multiple files. For this purpuse I have used the following command: ```(find . -not -path "./vendor/*" -name \*.php -exec echo "php -l -d display_errors=on '{}' &&"  \; ; echo "echo Done") | sh - ``` this will produce temp script with combining all lint checks with shell '&&' operator, which will produce non-zero exit code in case of error in any file

Comment: My favorite is Psalm (https://psalm.dev/).

Answer (score 38):

[Online PHP lint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html)

[PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/)

[Unitialized variables check](http://antirez.com/page/phplint.html). Link 1 and 2 already seem to do this just fine, though.

I can't say I have used any of these intensively, though :)

Comment: His answer made my day today be great! +1

Comment: PHPLint now seems to be hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/overtrue/phplint

Answer (score 27):

For completeness -- also check [phpCallGraph](http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 26):

[PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org) is awesome and fast.

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for an awesome. In fact, I refuse to use anything but awesome tools. :)

Comment: It's a start, and it seems to be what Netbeans uses, but I wouldn't trust it completely. Some of its options are just plain odd ("warning" you if you use an else statement??), and there are numerous big bugs in its detections, that haven't even had a response from the developers: https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/issues

Comment: else adds cyclomatic complexity and can often be written differently to avoid and else. e.g. if (true) { $x=1; } else { $x =2; } can be re-written: $x=2; if (true) { $x = 1; }

Answer (score 17):

I have tried using `php -l` and a couple of other tools.

However, the best one in my experience (your mileage may vary, of course) is [scheck of pfff toolset](https://github.com/facebook/pfff/wiki/Main). I heard about pfff on Quora (*[Is there a good PHP lint / static analysis tool?](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-good-PHP-lint-static-analysis-tool)*).

You can compile and install it. There are no nice packages (on my [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) Debian system, I had to install the *libpcre3-dev*, *ocaml*, *libcairo-dev*, *libgtk-3-dev* and *libgimp2.0-dev* dependencies first) but it should be worth an install.

The results are reported like

```
$ ~/sw/pfff/scheck ~/code/github/sc/
login-now.php:7:4: CHECK: Unused Local variable $title
go-automatic.php:14:77: CHECK: Use of undeclared variable $goUrl.
```

Comment: Thank you.  It keeps complaining about our dynamic imports, but its other capabilities look good so far.  I also needed to install binutils-gold, and scheck needed to be installed in a custom path, but it seems to work now.

Comment: @eswald Now a days I am a php mess detector (phpmd) convert. Of all the tools I have tried so far (php code sniffer, scheck, php -l, phpmd), IMHO, phpmd works best for my case.

Comment: Do you know where to find Scheck?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos scheck is part of pfff toolset. https://github.com/facebook/pfff

Comment: Scheck always give me the error "php checker needs a graph file".  The mostly non-existent documentation has no examples.

Comment: It is a hell to install all on Mac OS X.

Comment: @ Vladimir Vukanac maybe document the steps and publish for everyone?

Answer (score 14):

See [Semantic Designs' CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone), a "clone detection" tool that finds copy/paste/edited code.

It will find exact and near miss code fragments, in spite of white space, comments and even variable renamings. A sample detection report for PHP can be found at the website. (I'm the author.)

Comment: Looking at the site, that seems like an incredible tool. I will be taking a closer look later! Thanks for the link (+1 for "I'm the author" as well)

Comment: The bane of any conniving undergrad.

Answer (score 7):

The NetBeans IDE checks for syntax errors, unusued variables and such. It's not automated, but works fine for small or medium projects.

Comment: What is actually doing the checking? Isn't there some command-line tool that does the actual work? Or is it hardwired in?

Answer (score 6):

There a new tool called [nWire for PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php). It is a code exploration plugin for [Eclipse PDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and [Zend Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Studio) 7.x. It enables real-time code analysis for PHP and provides the following tools:

- Code visualization - interactive graphical representation of components and associations.
- Code navigation - unique navigation view shows all the associations and works with you while you write or read code.
- Quick search - search as you type for methods, fields, file, etc.

Comment: its not answer for question. like answer exist netbeans etc..

Answer (score 5):

[PHP PMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_(software)) (Programming Mistake Detector) and [PHP CPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_(software)#Copy/Paste_Detector_(CPD)) (Copy/Paste Detector) as the former part of [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit).

Answer (score 4):

There is [RIPS - A static source code analyser for vulnerabilities in PHP scripts](http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/#features). The source code of RIPS is available at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rips-scanner/?source=navbar).

From the RIPS site:

> RIPS is a tool written in PHP to find vulnerabilities in PHP
> applications using static code analysis. By tokenizing and parsing all
> source code files RIPS is able to transform PHP source code into a
> program model and to detect sensitive sinks (potentially vulnerable
> functions) that can be tainted by userinput (influenced by a malicious
> user) during the program flow. Besides the structured output of found
> vulnerabilities RIPS also offers an integrated code audit framework
> for further manual analysis.

Comment: RIPS is a half-dead project and it workes with non-OOP php-code only.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool for static code analysis called [PHP Analyzer](https://github.com/scrutinizer-ci/php-analyzer). PHP Analyzer is now a deprecated project, but you still can access it on the legacy branch.

Among many types of static analysis it also provides basic auto-fixing functionality, see [the documentation](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/tools/php/php-analyzer/).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try compiling with Facebook's [HipHop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP).

It does a static analysis on the entire project and may be what you're looking for.

[GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php)