# What alternatives are there for PHPLint that run under Windows?

Tags: php, windows, validation

I just finished a little 5000-line PHP application and are now going into testing and debugging. A short while before the end I stumbled upon PHPLint. I really liked the idea - with some special comments I can specify variable types and the tool then checks my code for all kinds of mistakes. Neat. I thought that at the end of the development I would comment my code and run PHPLint on it.

Unfortunately I ran into a little problem - PHPLint isn't compilable under Windows. Well, it is, but only with Cygwin, and I don't want to install THAT thing again. Nor do I want to get a virtual machine with Linux or something. Of course, I will, if there will be no other choices, but first I'd like to explore other options.

So - are there any alternatives for PHPLint that run under Windows? I mean in the sense of code-checking. I don't care about the documentation-generation part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPLint now runs under Windows. The download page is currently here: http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/download-windows.html

It's a command-line utility, but there's also a little GUI tool which requires a separate download of the Tcl/Tk interpreter from http://www.tcl.tk

Answer (score 2):

They don't work exactly like PHPLint, but there are a couple of static analysis tools listed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)

Answer (score -1):

OK, since there don't seem to be any good alternatives (those static analysis tools don't check variable types as far as I can tell), I installed a Slackware virtual machine. Clean, and gets things done. :)

If though there are some other good alternatives out there, don't hesitate to post them here. Even though I've found my solution, others might benefit from it too!

Comment: Can't you just compile the PHPLint c-source in Linux ?
SORRY ignore this comment :D