# 'AND' vs '&&' as operator

Tags: php, operators, operator-precedence

I have a codebase where developers decided to use `AND` and `OR` instead of `&&` and `||`.

I know that there is a difference in operators' precedence (`&&` goes before `and`), but with the given framework ([PrestaShop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PrestaShop) to be precise) it is clearly not a reason.

Which version are you using? Is `and` more readable than `&&`? Or is there no difference?

Comment: Note that `~` is the bit-wise NOT operator and not the logical. ;-)

Comment: Yes, i know. Bad habits :) . It is a little bit strange that in PHP there are  'and', 'or' and 'xor', but there is no 'not', isn't  it?

Comment: @ts: the correct answer here is the one provided by R. Bemrose
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator/2803576#2803576

Comment: ! is the logical not operator

Comment: @doublejosh your comment does not help anyone because who knows what answer you are referring to, and if the asker possibly already changed the answer? which answer is (or was) misleading?

Comment: @chiliNUT quite right. At the time it must have made sense. Looks like the lurking incorrect answer has been punished at this point :)

Comment: @doublejosh way to write back so quickly on a response to a comment from over a year ago, thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug in php. php should use natural language where possible and avoid random doodles. Lets leave the days of assembly behind please.

Answer (score 730, accepted):

If you use `AND` and `OR`, you'll eventually get tripped up by something like this:

```
$this_one = true;
$that = false;

$truthiness = $this_one and $that;
```

Want to guess what `$truthiness` equals?

If you said `false`... bzzzt, sorry, wrong!

`$truthiness` above has the value `true`.  Why?  `=` has a [higher precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `and`. The addition of parentheses to show the implicit order makes this clearer:

```
($truthiness = $this_one) and $that
```

If you used `&&` instead of `and` in the first code example, it would work as expected and be `false`.

As discussed in the comments below, this also works to get the correct value, as parentheses have higher precedence than `=`:

```
$truthiness = ($this_one and $that)
```

Comment: +1: this should be made loud and clear in PHP documentation, or PHP should change and give same precedence to these operators or DEPRECATE `and` `or` once for all. I saw too many people thinking they are exactly the same thing and the answers here are more testimonials.

Comment: Actually, other languages (for example, Perl and Ruby) also have these variants with the same precedence distinction so it wouldn't be sensible to deviate from this standard (however puzzling it might be for beginners) by making precedence equal in PHP. Not to mention the backward compatibility of tons of PHP applications.

Comment: People's inability to read the documentation for a language does not make the language's decisions wrong. As Mladen notes, Perl and Ruby also use these extra operators, and with the same precedences. It allows for constructs such as `$foo and bar()`, which are nice shortcuts for if statements. If unexpected behaviour (from bad documentation, or not reading it) were a reason not to use something we wouldn't be talking about using PHP at all.

Comment: I spent 3 minutes to find wrong line: **$this = true**, :( and what about $truthiness = ($this and $that); it's look better for me :)

Comment: I agree with Dmitriy - wrapping the boolean evaluation in parentheses helps to clarify the intent of the code.

I think the operator and it's function as they now exist are valuable and consistent with other languages, it's the job of the programmer to understand the language.

Comment: What about $truthiness = $this or $that; ?

Comment: @DmitriyKozmenko That would also be true. `$truthiness = $this or $that;` would be `true`, as would `$truthiness = $this || $that;` but I suspect you knew that already. `$truthiness = $that or $this;` would have `$truthiness` be equal to `false`, though.

Comment: I used to avoid && and || because I wrongly thought they were legacy and because they did not read as "English" but they are almost always what I want.

Comment: @zzapper Just remember that `&&` and `||` are also short-circuiting logic operators.  Basically, if the first argument to `&&` is false, the second argument is never evaluated.  Likewise for `||`, if the first argument is true, the second argument is never evaluated.

Comment: So it sets truthiness to true, but returns false.

That's even scarier than truthiness being true.

Comment: Using the same `$this and $that` would an `if ($this and $that)` statement execute its block ?

Comment: I said false and... it isn't? really?? I guess you wanted to mean $this=false and $that=true..

Comment: Whoever doesn't use parenthesis to show intent in their code is simply asking for it. Did they never learn how to do arithmetic? Hiding behind lazy coding practices and relying on innate precedence to never change, is blind arrogance. I strongly disagree with Marco's comment about `and` and `or` should be depreciated. All those upvoters should be ashamed of themselves ;)

Comment: I really like the readability of $is_fruit = ($is_apple or $is_banana);

Comment: When I run this example in the CLI I get false, both using Psy Shell and TinkerWell, but if I run the same example through a web server the answer is true.

Comment: What would happen if someone executed the code `($truthiness = $this_one) and $that`, though? Would this do anything?

Answer (score 48):

Depending on how it's being used, it might be necessary and even handy.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
// "||" has a greater precedence than "or"

// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

But in most cases it seems like more of a developer taste thing, like every occurrence of this that I've seen in CodeIgniter framework like @Sarfraz has mentioned.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "true" isn't ignored if that expression is part of a larger statement.  Consider the case `if ($f = false or true) $f = true;` - the result would be that `$f` does become true in the end, because the expression evaluates as true overall.

Comment: no, you simply overwrote the variable later. the expression still evaluated to false, then you overwrote it with true in the next line.

Comment: Actually, he was right. First, `$f` gets assigned false - but the condition evaluates to true, so then `$f` is overwritten. If the condition evaluated to false, `$f` would never been overwritten either way.

Comment: It's ridiculous to suggest the developers should follow their own taste. Forget the nightmare of another developer trying to maintain the same code, the developer who wrote the code itself would be making semantic mistakes in any code written because s/he preferred `and` over `&&`, where `and` works as expected in only some situations and `&&` works as expected in all situations.

Answer (score 16):

Since `and` has lower precedence than `=` you can use it in condition assignment:

```
if ($var = true && false) // Compare true with false and assign to $var
if ($var = true and false) // Assign true to $var and compare $var to false
```

Answer (score 13):

For safety, I always parenthesise my comparisons and space them out. That way, I don't have to rely on operator precedence:

```
if( 
    ((i==0) && (b==2)) 
    || 
    ((c==3) && !(f==5)) 
  )
```

Comment: Personally I think adding extra unnecessary parentheses makes it more confusing to read than having just what you need. For example, I think this is much easier to read:  if (($i == 0 && $b == 2) || ($c == 3 && $f != 5))

Comment: I think this is the prettiest piece of code I've looked at all day. Good job.

Comment: As PHP is an interpreted language it will run fast if you don't use unnecessary whitespaces or new lines on your code. If you do the same on a compiled language it only will take more time to compile but it will not take effect on runtime. I don't mean doing it once will mark a difference but on an entire application using php + javascript both wrote like the example... load times will be larger for sure. 

Explanation: Whitespaces and new lines are ignored, but to ignore them, they have to be checked. This happens at runtime on interpreted langs and when compiling on a compiled ones.

Comment: @JoelBonetR if you're using php opcache or similar your concern about load times is irrelevant. I'd hope nobody is running a production php site without it...

Comment: @PeloNZ so you can write dirty because it will be cached anyway and the entire project will take only a second more to load when refresh, huh? To code clean is for yourself and your teammates, concerning about timings was only a point that most people ignore or simply didn&#39;t know.

Comment: Whitespace is only for readability and has practically no effect on loading times. Do you write all your JS in minified form so as to save time running a JS compiler?

Answer (score 12):

Precedence differs between *&&* and *and* (&& has higher precedence than and), something that causes confusion when combined with a ternary operator. For instance,

```
$predA && $predB ? "foo" : "bar"
```

will return a *string* whereas

```
$predA and $predB ? "foo" : "bar"
```

will return a *boolean*.

Answer (score 3):

> Let me explain the difference between “and” - “&&” - "&".

"&&" and "and" both are **logical AND operations** and they do the same thing, but the operator precedence is different.

The precedence (priority) of an operator specifies how "tightly" it binds two expressions together. For example, in the expression 1 + 5 * 3, the answer is 16 and not 18 because the multiplication ("*") operator has a higher precedence than the addition ("+") operator.

*Mixing them together in single operation, could give you unexpected results in some cases*
I recommend always using &&, but that's your choice.

---

On the other hand "&" is a **bitwise AND operation**. It's used for the evaluation and manipulation of specific bits within the integer value.

Example if you do (14 & 7) the result would be 6.

```
7   = 0111
14  = 1110
------------
    = 0110 == 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Another nice example using `if` statements without `=` assignment operations.

```
if (true || true && false); // is the same as:
if (true || (true && false)); // TRUE
```

and

```
if (true || true AND false); // is the same as:
if ((true || true) && false); // FALSE
```

because `AND` has a lower precedence and thus `||` a higher precedence.

These are different in the cases of `true, false, false` and `true, true, false`.
See https://ideone.com/lsqovs for en elaborate example.

Answer (score 1):

> which version are you using?

If the coding standards for the particular codebase I am writing code for specifies which operator should be used, I'll *definitely* use that. If not, and the code *dictates* which should be used (not often, can be easily worked around) then I'll use that. Otherwise, *probably* `&&`.

> Is 'and' more readable than '&&'?

Is it more readable *to you*. The answer is *yes and no* depending on many factors including the code around the operator and indeed the person reading it!

> || there is ~ difference?

Yes. See [logical operators](http://php.net/operators.logical) for `||` and [bitwise operators](http://php.net/operators.bitwise) for `~`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a matter of taste, although (mistakenly) mixing them up might cause some undesired behaviors:

```
true && false || false; // returns false

true and false || false; // returns true
```

Hence, using && and || is safer for they have the highest precedence. In what regards to readability, I'd say these operators are universal enough.

**UPDATE**: About the comments saying that both operations return false ... well, in fact the code above does not return anything, I'm sorry for the ambiguity. To clarify: the behavior in the second case depends on how the result of the operation is used. Observe how the precedence of operators comes into play here:

```
var_dump(true and false || false); // bool(false)

$a = true and false || false; var_dump($a); // bool(true)
```

The reason why `$a === true` is because the assignment operator has precedence over any logical operator, as already very well explained in other answers.

Comment: This isn't true, they all return false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little counter example:

```
$a = true;
$b = true;
$c = $a & $b;
var_dump(true === $c);
```

output:

```
bool(false)
```

I'd say this kind of typo is far more likely to cause insidious problems (in much the same way as `=` vs `==`) and is far less likely to be noticed than `adn`/`ro` typos which will flag as syntax errors. I also find and/or is much easier to read. FWIW, most PHP frameworks that express a preference (most don't) specify and/or. I've also never run into a real, non-contrived case where it would have mattered.