# protect ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I use this to check in my registration page, if the email already exists on my database:

```
$('#email').blur(function() {
  var email = $(this).val();
  $.post('ajax/get_request/check',{key:"email",value:email},function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

It does works fine. However, I've noticed, if I access the ajax path via URL address bar of the browser, `http://example.com/ajax/get_request/check`, this displays blank. I tried this script to redirect if `value` is null.

```
//controller.php
public function check($key=NULL,$value=NULL)
{
  if(is_null($value)) redirect(base_url(),'refresh');
  // ... more scripts below ...
}
```

But this affect my ajax request response on registration. What I want to achieve here is to detect if the user access the ajax via registration form not when directly typing the path on the URL browser.

Comment: www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+check+if+request+is+made+via+ajax+or+via+browser&oq=how+to+check+if+request+is+made+via+ajax+or+via+browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301150/how-do-i-check-if-the-request-is-made-via-ajax-with-php

Comment: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is undefined in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request()
```

to check if the incoming request is an ajax request. This is available in codeigniter2

In your controller,

```
if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    //do your stuffs
}else{
  die("Access Prohibited.");
}
```