# How to check if the request is an AJAX request with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I would like to check server-side if a request to my php page is an ajax request or not.

I saw two ways to do this:

First way: sending a `GET` parameter in the request which tells the page that this is an AJAX request (=`mypage.php?ajax`)

mypage.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    //this is an ajax request, process data here.
}
```

Second way: set a header to the `xmlHttpRequest`:

client-side js:

```
xmlHttpRequestObject.open(“GET”,url,true);
xmlHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

mypage.php:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
    //request is ajax
}
```

---

The fact is, those two ways of doing it can easily be hacked, so it's not secure to check if i get an AJAX request like this.

How can i check if i'm receiving an AJAX request?

Comment: Just keep in mind: "NEVER trust the client side". You cannot know from where a request is made. You could spoof/disguise/fake (almost) everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301150/how-do-i-check-if-the-request-is-made-via-ajax-with-php

Comment: @ChristianGärtner I know that, that's why i posted the question. I don't think there is a 100% safe way to do it, but i think there must be a way to make it tricky for "hackers" to fake the request (maybe managing it server-side)

Comment: @J.Robertson As written in the question, i tried to do it as is answered in the question you linked, but it can easily be spoofed.

Comment: "hackers" would see through any "tricky" stuff. there is literally NOTHING you can do to 100% reliably tell is an http request is "legit" or "faked".

Comment: @MarcB Yes, but if it's tricky it will be harder for them to fake it. It's not 100% safe, there isn't a 100% safe way, but this could be a good start.

Comment: at best you can put a very minor speedbump in the "hacker's" path. just remember that ajax is just a perfectly normal http request. other than the fact that it tens to have been initiated by some javascsript as a background request within a web page, there is absolutely no standard method of deciding if it's ajax or something the user clicked on/submitted. the presence/abscence of the X headers is not a guarantee of anything

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no sure-fire way of knowing that a request was made via Ajax. You can never trust data coming from the client. You could use a couple of different methods but they can be easily overcome by spoofing.

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure there isn't a 100% safe way to do it. But i think that there must be a way to make it tricky for "hackers" to fake the request (maybe managing it server side?)

Comment: @BackSlash You could make it tricky, but that would be security through obscurity. Personally, I wouldn't rely on it. Your best bet would probably be tokens that change per-request. Or a captcha.

Comment: I was thinking about cookies, are they sent with an ajax request?

Comment: An Ajax request is basically just a HTTP request that is sent without the user having to leave the page. Anything you can do with a HTTP request can also be done in an Ajax request :) Wouldn't rely on cookies either though!

Comment: @BackSlash: I found a nice article, have a look: http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/10/web-security-using-crumbs-to-protect-your-php-api-ajax-call-from-cross-site-request-forgery-csrfxsrf-and-other-vulnerabilities/

Comment: `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
}`

Comment: but what is the security risks here? the headers can be spoofed ... so what? it is just an ajax request that is accessible from the public ... spoof or not...

Comment: @yeahman That would depend on the purpose of the check. e.g. Trying to prevent non-Ajax requests.

Answer (score 80):

Example from an [archived tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326091033/http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-php-to-detect-an-ajax-request):

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ?? '') === 'xmlhttprequest')
{    
    // We can assume that request was made with AJAX   
}
```

This checks if the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` parameter is set and its value is equal to `xmlhttprequest`.

Comment: This answer is EXTREMELY relevant now because the facebook android app sends with `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH=com.facebook.katana.` Adding in the last check  `== 'xmlhttprequest'` You need to implement this check of type witht he new facebook browser, otherwise strange things can happen.

Comment: I often use this as an additional hurdle for scrapers to contend with, it's not foolproof but it's effective in some cases...
As `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` may be undefined I recommend a slight edit.
`if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')`...

Comment: Hello from 2021,

This code is working fine if user is using jQuery ajax such as `.ajax()`, `.post()` but with vanilla JS `XMLHttpRequest()`, or `.fetch()` they don't send this header anymore.

Answer (score 15):

From PHP 7 with null coalescing operator it will be shorter:

```
$is_ajax = 'xmlhttprequest' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ?? '' );
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is frequently undefined.

Answer (score 10):

This function is used from the Yii PHP Framework to check for an AJAX call.

```php
public function isAjax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Set a session variable for every page on your site (actual pages not includes or rpcs) that contains the current page name, then in your Ajax call pass a nonce salted with the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];`

```
<?php
function create_nonce($optional_salt='')
{
    return hash_hmac('sha256', session_id().$optional_salt, date("YmdG").'someSalt'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
$_SESSION['current_page'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
?>

<form>
  <input name="formNonce" id="formNonce" type="hidden" value="<?=create_nonce($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);?>">
  <label class="form-group">
    Login<br />
    <input name="userName" id="userName" type="text" />
  </label>
  <label class="form-group">
    Password<br />
    <input name="userPassword" id="userPassword" type="password" />
  </label>
  <button type="button" class="btnLogin">Sign in</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form.login button").on("click", function() {
        authorize($("#userName").val(),$("#userPassword").val(),$("#formNonce").val());
    });

    function authorize (authUser, authPassword, authNonce) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/inc/rpc.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: "userID="+authUser+"&password="+authPassword+"&nonce="+authNonce
        })
        .success(function( msg ) {
            //some successful stuff
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then in the rpc you are calling test the nonce you passed, if it is good then odds are pretty great that your rpc was legitimately called:

```
<?php
function check_nonce($nonce, $optional_salt='')
{
    $lasthour = date("G")-1<0 ? date('Ymd').'23' : date("YmdG")-1;
    if (hash_hmac('sha256', session_id().$optional_salt, date("YmdG").'someSalt'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == $nonce || 
        hash_hmac('sha256', session_id().$optional_salt, $lasthour.'someSalt'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == $nonce)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$ret = array();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (check_nonce($_POST['nonce'], $_SESSION['current_page']))
{
    $ret['nonce_check'] = 'passed';
} else {
    $ret['nonce_check'] = 'failed';
}
echo json_encode($ret);
exit;
?>
```

edit: FYI the way I have it set the nonce is only good for an hour and change, so if they have not refreshed the page doing the ajax call in the last hour or 2 the ajax request will fail.

Comment: This is more a CSRF Protection than a way to decide if it was a regular GET/POST request or an ajax request.

Answer (score 5):

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$is_ajax = (isset($headers['X-Requested-With']) && $headers['X-Requested-With'] == 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Comment: Some headers can easily be spoofed. `X-Requested-With` is one of them, as it's set by the client. That's why I don't want to use it.

Comment: Yes, it's not safe, but if you simply need to decide on the format of the answer, you can use it.

Comment: This NOT work with android facebook app, set the x-request-with to com.facebook.katana !

Answer (score 1):

Try below code snippet

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
   && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
  {
    /* This is one ajax call */
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use HTTP_SEC

```
  if (!array_key_exists("HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE",$_SERVER) || $_SERVER["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE"] != "same-origin")
    die(header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"));
  if (!array_key_exists("HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE",$_SERVER) || $_SERVER["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE"] != "cors")
    die(header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"));
  if (!array_key_exists("HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST",$_SERVER) || $_SERVER["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST"] != "empty")
    die(header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is able to detect AJAX request in three different ways:

- using `X-Requested-With` header
- using `Accept: application/json`
- fall-back to `?ajax=1` in the URL (make sure to add that manually)

```
    /**
     * http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php#70810
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjax()
    {
        $headers = function_exists('apache_request_headers') ? apache_request_headers() : [];
        if (!$headers) {
            $headers = [
                'X-Requested-With' => ifsetor($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
            ];
        }
        $headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_LOWER);

        $isXHR = false;
        if (isset($headers['x-requested-with'])) {
            $isXHR = $headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
        }

        $acceptJson = str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ?? '', 'application/json');

        return $this->getBool('ajax') || $isXHR || $acceptJson;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

`if ($request->ajax()) { //write code here }`

Answer (score -8):

You could try using a `$_SESSION` variable to make sure that a request was made from a browser.  Otherwise, you could have the request sent through a database or file [server-side].

Comment: how can you define `$_SESSION` from client?