# How can i block some webpages in my website for users, so that they can not open them directly from browser?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, server, hta

i have some pages which will be used internal ajax post form processing. like these

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function tab(x) 
{
        var x

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'catagory_tab.php',
        data: {

            y: x

              },
        success: function(html)
      {
      $("#result").html(html).show();
      }     
         });  
         return false; 
}

</script>
```

now if a user sees my webpage source code ( right click on page and view source code ) the the person will the "catagory_tab.php" page. then curiously he/she can open the page from browser. like typing www.example.com/catagory_tab.php. Then code will run from my page. So how to block this. i need that page for ajax post , but do not want that users can not open them directly.

Comment: Add a check of some sort at the top of the page that redirects the user.

Comment: Check this: [How to check if the request is an AJAX request with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260537/how-to-check-if-the-request-is-an-ajax-request-with-php)

Comment: Hi did you check the answer I've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in the top of that particular page.

```
// No direct access to this file 
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');if(!IS_AJAX) {die('Restricted access');}
```

Comment: hey buddy it worked, but it still opens the page  and shows 'Restricted access'; Can i not show another massage ???

Comment: simply you can add code to redirect to some other page like index of the site.