# Angular 'Uncaught error: Zone already loaded'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angular

[Errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJUIp.png)

I am using a Mailchimp Ajax Submit jQuery Plugin to submit an email using a PHP file on a contact form in a website template I imported to my Angular app. When I go to enter my details on the form and submit, the page refreshes on the POST request.

The console then throws the following two errors.

**[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest**

```js
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest 
on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the 
end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
(anonymous) @ polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1
polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1
```

**Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.**

```python
Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
at polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1
at polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1
at Object.0TWp (polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1)
at p (<anonymous>:1:507)
at Object.hN/g (polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1)
at p (<anonymous>:1:507)
at Object.5 (polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js:1)
at p (<anonymous>:1:507)
at n (<anonymous>:1:376)
at e (<anonymous>:1:248)
```

I am finding it difficult to understand the cause of the problem. I have tried to prevent the page from refreshing on submit using `<button type="button">`, this does not do a page refresh however it does not call a POST request as expected.
I have also tried un-commenting `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` in **polyfills.ts**

I wish to accomplish sending the email on the same page without a refresh in the Angular app unless there is a better alternative. (I am learning)

**main.js**

```
var clContactForm = function() {

    /* local validation */
    $('#contactForm').validate({

        /* submit via ajax */
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            var sLoader = $('.submit-loader');

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() { 

                    sLoader.slideDown("slow");

                },
                success: function(msg) {

                    // Message was sent
                    if (msg == 'OK') {
                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').fadeOut();
                        $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                        $('.message-success').fadeIn();
                    }
                    // There was an error
                    else {
                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').html(msg);
                        $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");
                    }

                },
                error: function() {

                    sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                    $('.message-warning').html("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
                    $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");

                }

            });
        }

    });
};
```

**sendEmail.php**

```
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'my-email';


if($_POST) {

$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
$contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

// Check Name
if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
}
// Check Email
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
}
// Check Message
if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
    $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
}
// Subject
if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


// Set Message
$message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
$message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
$message .= "Message: <br />";
$message .= $contact_message;
$message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

// Set From: header
$from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

// Email Headers
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


if (!$error) {

    ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
    $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
    else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

} # end if - no validation error

else {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : 
null;

        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the JavaScript files for Angular have been loaded into the web page twice. I think what might be happening is that `$.ajax()` is receiving a full HTML page in the response which includes the JavaScript headers. So the file `polyfills.c5fb4ffca9c225046d5a.js` is getting loaded again. Look at the response data in the *network* tab of Chrome dev tools, and see if there is a full HTML file in the POST response.

Comment: @cgTag thanks for your reply. I checked the POST response for **sendEmail.php** and you're correct, it is the full page of **index.html**.

Just to add, the **sendEmail.php** response should just be the text 'OK'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260537/how-to-check-if-the-request-is-an-ajax-request-with-php

Comment: @cgTag I had a look at that link and tried using an if statement to test if the request was AJAX. Unsure what it's used for since I still got a full HTML page in the response. I have tried using `dataType: "text"` in the JS script and `exit();` before closing the if `$_POST` in PHP also with no luck.