# Only accept AJAX $_GET or $_POST requests from specific page

Tags: php, ajax

Is it possible to check that the `$_GET` or `$_POST` values are submitted from specific page?

For example, there is an `ajax` in `page1` submitted value to `page2.php?q=abc`, and the `page2` only accept the `q` when it is submitted from `page1`.

If I directly browse to the page `page2.php?q=abc`, the `php` will not run unless I submitted the value from `page1`.

Is it possible to do that?

Edit 1:

Because I can access the `page2` and get the result. Don't mention about the `session`, because I can validate the `session` to match my needs and the values submitted to php is valid or not.

What I want is to check if the request is sent from specific page or not. If true, then accept the values and process it, else, redirect to homepage or something else.

Edit 2:
My question is, not only values submitted through Ajax, but also direct access, such as `href="page2.php?q=abc"`. I guess token will be the best way to do that, and the query part will validate again.

Comment: Explain the original intentions. Why do you need that?

Comment: if you are submitting values then it means you are submitting form and what method a form will have it depends on you

Comment: My favorite mechanism to do this is with tokens, produce a token on the form and store it in a database, and check its validity when posted, delete the token once used.

Comment: Anything that comes from the dark dangerous internet is possibly compromised. Anything you might try to enforce this could possibly be spoofed. That said, setting a $_SESSION variable might give you a method

Comment: maybe you were looking for this? check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301150/how-do-i-check-if-the-request-is-made-via-ajax-with-php)

Comment: So basically, you are looking to validate that a request is not a forgery from an unexpected source. My suggestion would be to use a validation token to compare against a similar token in session. This is something you Should be doing anyway for secure form handling.

Comment: As a sidenote you could add one more restriction, that is checking whether the request is only coming from AJAX. Or you could send in a hashed string which you can decrypt at page2.php to make sure the page1.php has sent the request.

Comment: @MikeBrant, yes, token is one of the way.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, is there such function to check the request is only coming from Ajax? Can you show me an example?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] can be used to detect Ajax request. IN case of ajax request it returns the XmlHttpRequest value. However according to online resources, It may not be supported by all servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if the request is an AJAX request with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260537/how-to-check-if-the-request-is-an-ajax-request-with-php)

Comment: @esqew, may be it's a duplicate to you. But my question is not only limited to Ajax, such as a `href` with values. Hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two security checks you could perform while dealing with AJAX:

#### 1) Check if the request it sent through AJAX:

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' )
{
       //AJAX Request Detected
}
```

#### 2) Hashed tokens:

On the page that's holding the AJAX Request, create a token:

```
session_start();
$hashed='';
$_SESSION['token'] = microtime(); 
if (defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) {
    $salt = '$2y$11$' . substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 22);
    $hashed = crypt($_SESSION['token'], $salt);
}
```

This is using the `blowfish` algorithm with the **[crypt()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)** to create hashed string.

Your AJAX function would be like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'page2.php',
    data: {
        action: '<?php echo $hashed;?>', //pasted the hashed string created in PHP
        q: 'test'
    },
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

Upto you whether you want to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` method.

And then on the second page which is receiving the AJAX request, you do:

```
session_start();
if(crypt($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['action']) == $_POST['action']){
   //Hashed string matches. Request has come from page1.
   echo $_POST['q'];
}
```

Comment: this was exactly what i was gonna suggest.

Answer (score 1):

in your form you can just add a hidden field and add a page id. On the page that should send post or get request you can do something like

```
<form action='phpscript.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='page' value='valid_page'>
    <input name='your_other_info'>
</form>
```

In the phpscript.php you can do something like

```
<?php
    //If you have a request, it can be either post or get method
    if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && (isset($_POST['page']) || isset($_GET['page']))){

    }else{
        //Post or get is not from the valid page
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the "origin" of the request, because there's no such thing per se. Your "page" isn't sending a request, it's the browser that does it. And the browser may have any number of reasons why it's sending you a request; be that because one of your pages has instructed it to do so or because a user is fiddling around with the Javascript console manually.

All you get on your end is an HTTP request. Go ahead, inspect it. In the browser, look at the network tab and inspect the raw request being sent. It's just a bunch of HTTP headers, nothing more. Anyone can send an HTTP request with arbitrary HTTP headers any time from anywhere and make it look like anything they want. Even the Referer HTTP header is not going to "protect" you.

If you need any sort of protection, you can use session tokens or user authentication to restrict the set of potential entities that can send queries somewhat. But what you have is still by definition a public URL endpoint which answers to arbitrary HTTP queries. You cannot restrict their "origin page". The best you can do is obfuscate it by requiring certain headers to be set (like Referer or X-Requested-With).

Comment: You make it sound completely hopeless, but it's not. There are many cases where the "referrer" header *does*provide essential security. For an AJAX request, the "referer" HTTP header contains the URL which originated the request. This is extremely useful, because it serves as evidence for where any AJAX request came from. This is often good enough for cross-site scripting protection: JavaScript which is injected on page A cannot spoof the "referrer" header to make it look like it is from page B.