# How to get row position?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by)
>   [Calculating rank in PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845290/calculating-rank-in-php-mysql)

I have a game system wrote in php, each user has X amount of money.
I have a page that display the most rich users in the site.

```
$ranking = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    ORDER BY money DESC 
    LIMIT 10
");
```

Now I want give each user his position in the list.
I can't select all the information and start to sort just to get one value, it's waste of resources.
How can I select the position of a row (where userid = X)?

(MYSQL)

Comment: @RedFilter, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and standard way to do this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM users WHERE money > u.money) as MoneyRank
FROM users AS u
WHERE username = 'X'
```

Here is a [SqlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4edef/2).

This does suffer from performance problems as any ["triangular join"](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) (SQL Server article, but still applies) would, however.  I would still implement it myself this way initially (it's simple), then index if there's a performance problem, then move on to other pre-calculated/cached options if that's not good enough.  The comments also mention other solutions that would work.

Answer (score 0):

`Rank` column would be the position in the list:

```
SELECT t.*, 
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM users, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY money DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I've tried to edit and add the WHERE clause that I need, anyway, it always gives me 1 and not the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily/quickly without doing a full table sort. I'd recommend that you only give each person a new rank periodically, perhaps every hour, and update their position in that way.

For the "leaderboard", you don't run into this issue, because you will always have the offset and limit restrictions. So when you display the top 10 (limited), you know their ranks of 1 - 10.

However, just selecting an individual user, you can't do this without a *highly* inneficient table sort.

Also, see this other question, which (I think is a near exact duplicate?)

[Calculating rank in PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845290/calculating-rank-in-php-mysql)

Comment: I don't mind to do a full table sort, but I want get the result in the resource, and not sort in php.