# Unknown "half" error

Tags: php, html

I have problem in my PHP code. I'm trying to make internet shop and Im now in product listing step. My code is so long, so I will show only substantial part.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, category, describtion, value FROM products") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) % 2 == 0)
{
    while($left = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) && $right = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        echo '
        <div class="sub_items">
        <div class="sub_left">

                <div class="sub_items_header">
                <h1>'.$left[0].'</h1>
                <h2>'.$left[1].'</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="sub_items_image">
                <img src="images/'.$left[0].'.png" width="167" height="164" alt="'.$left[0].'" />
                </div>

                <div class="sub_items_text">
                    '.$left[2].'
                </div>

                <div class="sub_items_cartinfo">
                    <div class="price">
                    <h2>'.$left[3].'$</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="addtocart">
                    <a href="chart.php?name='.$left[0].'"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearthis">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearthis">&nbsp;</div>

            </div>
            <div class="sub_right">

                <div class="sub_items_header">
                <h1>'.$right[0].'</h1>
                <h2>'.$right[1].'</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="sub_items_image">
                <img src="images/'.$right[0].'.png" width="175" height="170" alt="'.$right[0].'" />
                </div>

                <div class="sub_items_text">
                    '.$right[2].'
                </div>

                <div class="sub_items_cartinfo">
                    <div class="price">
                    <h2>'.$right[3].'$</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="addtocart">
                    <a href="chart.php?name='.$right[0].'"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearthis">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearthis">&nbsp;</div>

            </div>

            <!-- End of Right Sub Item -->

            <div class="clearthis">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>
        <div class="h_divider">&nbsp;</div>
            ';
    }
```

In the while cycle I'm echoing data. Data is separated to left and right div. I'm not getting any error message, but I have bad output. Look.
[image: ...]

The left side not loads, but right yes. Why? Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

= has a higher precedence thaN AND; use AND instead of && or parenthesize the assignments.

Instead of

```
$left = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) && $right = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)
```

either

```
$left = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) AND $right = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)
```

or

```
($left = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) && ($right = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
```

Comment: Thre's not problem in images! There's problem in data whitch does not loads. Look. In first half, there is no text and title, but in left it is.

Comment: Well, maybe the values in the db are actually empty? Also, one of your cols are named "describtion" instead of "description"? Can it be a typo?

Comment: If they were empty, I might not put it here.

Comment: I replaced && with AND and it works! WHy?

Comment: = has a higher precedence that AND. That may be why. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/72436