# PHP operator difference && and "and"

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Sorry for very basic question but I started learning PHP just a week ago & couldn't find an answer to this question on google/stackoverflow.

I went through below program:

```
$one = true;
$two = null;
$a = isset($one) && isset($two);
$b = isset($one) and isset($two);

echo $a.'<br>';
echo $b;
```

Its output is:

```
false
true
```

I read &&/and are same. How is the result different for both of them? Can someone tell the real reason please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Among three operators you used `&&`, `and` & `=`, precedence order is

- `&&`
- `=`
- `and`

So `$a` in your program calculated as expected but for `$b`, statement `$b = isset($one)` was calculated first, giving unexpected result. It can be fixed as follow.

```
$b = (isset($one) and isset($two));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats how the grouping of operator takes place

```
$one = true;
$two = null;
$a = (isset($one) && isset($two));
($b = isset($one)) and isset($two);

echo $a.'<br>';
echo $b;
```

Thats why its returning false for first and true for second.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

It explains that "and" is different from "&&" in that the order of operations is different. Assignment happens first in that case. So if you were to do:

```
$b = (isset($one) and isset($two));
```

You'd end up with the expected result.