# Rename file depending on select option

Tags: php, file, if-statement, file-rename

I have an upload system which uses the following code to define the file name:

```
$file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
```

I have added a selectbox with a few options and what I want to do, is add add a word to the beginning of the filename, depending on which option is selected.

The if statement for the selectbox works fine however I'm a little stuck with adding the word "`skin_`" onto the beginning of the name. So far, I have this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload_type']) and $_POST['upload_type'] == 'skin') {
    $file_name = "skin_", trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
}
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You concat strings in PHP using `.` (a dot) instead of a `,`:

```
$file_name = "skin_" . trim(basename(stripslashes($name)) . ".\x00..\x20");
```

Comment: ah that was the mistake, thanks so much...+1.... I'll accept when it allows me to

Comment: You're very welcome. Maybe a little note: be careful using `and` instead of `&&` - it can get tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/1456376 :)