# $_GET function in php not working correctly

Tags: php

im using this URL:

```
http://domain.co.uk/iphone/index.php?c=knnKVLO4ROKPvvtxUCDu&bhsirf=Q8IP6OKRtaOCjcCgpb94&9froifhew3=ux9XI0vjKfzieTVS6rTt&40289njgw=We80L1RXDPIQj4ENL3QM&AdjoirtGERG^%%C2%A3fd=ozS60iysc1Vd9QgVDZIP&jorw4958fq%C2%A3$=2kbCk7EXRNMZlYMhDdkhVm2E3j4sNDtmo8ho2Ag6&ffjg^GDDFGn2FFGHe=8fuTCaTzKbf1VYQPcornK8LOK4ERPT43XoegnvTByli9c1rIInTwvwvShxkN&a@@^%45383fhreFGGew=48bFy4U6bBYcMqLHnVfK2kbCk7EXRNMZlYMhDdkh&fGHDFb.fewfrgopewFRWGREG=gbBYKubAEk7DcpQ69M7ZkxVGa2aSWiYlrEXOUqDINYsKnnMhf0hHqhQGdMUS9M3Zy74em2NIrubulwS5XcPmgHytg8we8f1y9aR2&gfiegrowu895743fdGTRY%C2%A3QT%C2%A3%yewhfuigw9545TRWTRYEgsgfnfht34o=vXBuTfXODHxQsHJZH9MQx4TrFZ38eaEmm5eowcKVgeH69YYGWofJQI0Y4jE9GDhFrHdFhMc2Tqtlb4LwWEO47z5IrEp42QppEYMlLzx4yIFlxpNZ3g4gU384DqYPNo9c3Ks2RGGNEVaMhJNewC6g48WHeEhP6r5tfOpI5OyCsNiukHXfoAqVxtaggqt6xkce74hP4f22
```

and then this in my PHP:

```
<?php
if($_GET["c"] == 'knnKVLO4ROKPvvtxUCDu' and $_GET["bhsirf"] == 'Q8IP6OKRtaOCjcCgpb94' and $_GET["9froifhew3"] == 'ux9XI0vjKfzieTVS6rTt' and $_GET["40289njgw"] == 'We80L1RXDPIQj4ENL3QM' and $_GET["AdjoirtGERG^%£fd"] == 'ozS60iysc1Vd9QgVDZIP' and $_GET["jorw4958fq£$"] == '2kbCk7EXRNMZlYMhDdkhVm2E3j4sNDtmo8ho2Ag6' and $_GET["ffjg^GDDFGn2FFGHe"] == '8fuTCaTzKbf1VYQPcornK8LOK4ERPT43XoegnvTByli9c1rIInTwvwvShxkN' and $_GET["a@@^%45383fhreFGGew"] == '48bFy4U6bBYcMqLHnVfK2kbCk7EXRNMZlYMhDdkh' and $_GET["fGHDFb.fewfrgopewFRWGREG"] == 'gbBYKubAEk7DcpQ69M7ZkxVGa2aSWiYlrEXOUqDINYsKnnMhf0hHqhQGdMUS9M3Zy74em2NIrubulwS5XcPmgHytg8we8f1y9aR2' and $_GET["gfiegrowu895743fdGTRY£QT£%yewhfuigw9545TRWTRYEgsgfnfht34o"] == 'vXBuTfXODHxQsHJZH9MQx4TrFZ38eaEmm5eowcKVgeH69YYGWofJQI0Y4jE9GDhFrHdFhMc2Tqtlb4LwWEO47z5IrEp42QppEYMlLzx4yIFlxpNZ3g4gU384DqYPNo9c3Ks2RGGNEVaMhJNewC6g48WHeEhP6r5tfOpI5OyCsNiukHXfoAqVxtaggqt6xkce74hP4f22')
{
    //fine
}
else
{
    header("Location: /iphone/error.php");
}
?>
```

but its redirecting to error.php page even though everything is correct. are my strings too long or is there something else wrong?

heres the var_dump for $_GET:

```
errorarray(10) { ["index_php?c"]=> string(20) "knnKVLO4ROKPvvtxUCDu" ["bhsirf"]=> string(20) "Q8IP6OKRtaOCjcCgpb94" ["9froifhew3"]=> string(20) "ux9XI0vjKfzieTVS6rTt" ["40289njgw"]=> string(20) "We80L1RXDPIQj4ENL3QM" ["AdjoirtGERG^%£fd"]=> string(20) "ozS60iysc1Vd9QgVDZIP" ["jorw4958fq£$"]=> string(40) "2kbCk7EXRNMZlYMhDdkhVm2E3j4sNDtmo8ho2Ag6" ["ffjg^GDDFGn2FFGHe"]=> string(60) "8fuTCaTzKbf1VYQPcornK8LOK4ERPT43XoegnvTByli9c1rIInTwvwvShxkN" ["a@@^E383fhreFGGew"]=> string(40) "48bFy4U6bBYcMqLHnVfK2kbCk7EXRNMZlYMhDdkh" ["fGHDFb_fewfrgopewFRWGREG"]=> string(100) "gbBYKubAEk7DcpQ69M7ZkxVGa2aSWiYlrEXOUqDINYsKnnMhf0hHqhQGdMUS9M3Zy74em2NIrubulwS5XcPmgHytg8we8f1y9aR2" ["gfiegrowu895743fdGTRY£QT£%yewhfuigw9545TRWTRYEgsgfnfht34o"]=> string(200) "vXBuTfXODHxQsHJZH9MQx4TrFZ38eaEmm5eowcKVgeH69YYGWofJQI0Y4jE9GDhFrHdFhMc2Tqtlb4LwWEO47z5IrEp42QppEYMlLzx4yIFlxpNZ3g4gU384DqYPNo9c3Ks2RGGNEVaMhJNewC6g48WHeEhP6r5tfOpI5OyCsNiukHXfoAqVxtaggqt6xkce74hP4f22" }
```

Comment: Have you verified the content of `$_GET` via the output of `var_dump($_GET);`?

Comment: ive never done this before but see what i got in my questions

Comment: That `index_php?c` is suspect. Do you have any rewrite rules in place which are performing a catch-all rewrite?  Check your server config or .htaccess...

Comment: it seems to work ok if i do $_GET["a"] == '1234' and $_GET["b"] == '5678'

Comment: I donw know purpose of this, but looks pretty ugly

Answer (score 1):

Found one error:

You use the following key which does not exist in the array:

```
$_GET["fGHDFb.fewfrgopewFRWGREG"]
```

This one exists though:

```
$_GET["fGHDFb_fewfrgopewFRWGREG"]
```

(See Amirs answer for explanation).

Also, $_GET["c"] is not a valid key. Somehow, maybe because of a rewrite rule (as suggested by Michael Berkowski in comments to your question), it is changed to $_GET["index_php?c"].

With that said, your solution does not seem optimal, because you risk running into problems like these... What are you exactly trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For
> example `<input name="a.b" /> becomes $_GET["a_b"]` [refer here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the issue has to do with operator precedence `and` and && are not equal.

I would try replacing `and` with `&&`.

Comment: That's not an error, both `and` and `&&` are valid: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @Niko your right sorry haven't messed with php in a while.  It is still possible that my suggestion is worth trying since `and` and `&&` have different precedence.

Comment: I think you may have a point. `and` has lower precedence than `=`, which may apply to `==` as well, making it possible to mess with his final truth value.

Comment: @Niko Valid but not the same... var_dump(true and false) will return you true !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Comment: @0x1gene No, it returns false as expected: http://codepad.viper-7.com/t464Ma

Comment: @Niko and @0x1gene: Read my comments and learn! `=` has higher precedence than `and`. This results in the behavior here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fbKhB9

Comment: @FrederikWordenskjold How does that apply to the use of `and` vs `&&` in an if condition (with `==` rather than `=`, which are different operators)? I don't see your point here.

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second codes your posted seems to be OK for me but for some reason you are redirected to the error page.
The user "Frederik Wordenskjold" stated a difference of keys you might want to see if it is OK.
My suggestion to solve this problem or at least get a clue of where it is would be to print every $_GET you receive in that file (comment the "if-else" statement just to test this) so you can realise if the problem is in the file you are looking or in what you receive through $_GET