# Difference between && and and operator in PHP

Tags: php

Why does this evaluate true?
`$test = true and false;`

And this not?
`$test = (true and false);`

With the && operator it both evaluates to false, which is what I also would expect with the and operator. Apparently they are not interchangable, apart from the fact that they have a different precedence.

Comment: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Comment: I found the answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/1630609

Comment: `$test = true and false;` does **NOT** evaluate to true, but false. But **it sets $test to true**. The complete statement should evaluate to false, as `$test = true` evaluates to true (and sets $test to true), but the remaining ` and false;` makes the statement evaluate to **false**

Comment: In other words `if ($test = true and false) { /*should not execute */ }` just like `if ($test = (true and false)) { /*should not execute */ }`. In both cases they evaluate to false!

Answer (score 7):

"&&" has a greater precedence than "and"

```
// The result of the expression (true && false) is assigned to $g
// Acts like: ($g = (true && false))
$g = true && false;

// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;

var_dump($g, $h);
```

---

prints false, true

Comment: This is useful to make an assignment and a comparison in the same line without parentesis: `if ($a = true and $b)` will assing `true` to `$a` then resolve the logical operation. If the expression is evalutated to `true`, you can use the value of `$a` in the `if` block scope. This is equivalent to: `if (($a = true) && $b)`.

Comment: short and clear answer. This is what we need in stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same except for [Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

`&&` > `=` > `and` in the precedence table so your first example is equivalent to: `($test = true) and false;`