# IF statement is not checking all condition in PHP

Tags: php

```
if ($fname <> "" and $lname <> "" and $theemail <> "" and $empid <> "" and $doh <> "" and $ydept <> "#") {
    if ($percentage >= 85) {
        mail ($myEmail, $mailSubject, $msgBody, $header);
        mail ($userEmail, $sentMailSubject, $sentMailBody, $sentHeader);
        $filename = "output_annualexam.txt"; #Must CHMOD to 666, set folder to 777
        $text = "\n" . str_pad($fname, 25) . "" . str_pad($lname, 25) . "" . str_pad($empID, 15) . "" . str_pad($doh, 15) . "" . str_pad($tdate, 20) . "" . str_pad($ydept, 44) . "" . str_pad($percentage, 0) . "%";

        $fp = fopen ($filename, "a"); # a = append to the file. w = write to the file (create new if doesn't exist)
        if ($fp) {
            fwrite ($fp, $text);
            fclose ($fp);
            #echo ("File written");
        }
        else {
            #echo ("File was not written");
        }
        header ("Location: congrats.php?fname=$fname&type=$type");
    }
    else {
        header ("Location: nopass.php?percent=$percentage&type=$type");
    }
}
else {
    header ("Location: tryagain.php?type=$type");
}
```

When $ydept=="#" it means the user did not select any department from the SELECT options which will make the IF statement fail, which should automatically take the user to the tryagain.php page but instead it's taking them to the nopass.php page. So somewhere it's failing.

Should I try **&&** instead of **AND**? But I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: It could make a difference because of [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), where `&&` has a higher precedence than `and`.

Comment: But shouldn't it check for ALL condition?

Comment: Try `var_dump($ydept)` and see what happens.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the $ydept <> "#" (because when i left $fname blank, tryagain.php kicked in correctly)

Comment: Since it's a SELECT, do I have to use "$ydept = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['yDept'])));" to prevent any XSS attack? Or is it safe to say $ydept = $_POST['yDept']; (Maybe that's why it's not working?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use `&&` not `AND`.

Since I am not eloquent enough to explain it, here's a good post about it, thanks to the commentator ;)

['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator/2803576#2803576)

Comment: It does matter in PHP. When you use && it evaluates the entire expression. When you use AND it stops at the variable. See the answer that one links TO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/2360157 - My team just removed AND from our application and it solved several logic errors the previous programmer was not aware of because they didn't know && vs AND

Comment: I will change and test it now... Thanks!

Comment: I changed to && and it's still going to NOPASS.php

Comment: Why would it make a difference in this case, where `and` only appears parenthesized, and it *should* have a lower precedence than `<>`? You need to be able to explain why it should work. -1

Comment: I think it might have to do with the $ydept <> "#" (because when i left $fname blank, tryagain.php kicked in correctly) (What I am trying to do is, if $ydept anything other then "#" let the user continue.)

Comment: @minitech fair enough *shrug*

Comment: (!empty($ydept) && $ydept <> "#") solved the problem.