# Combine strpos !== false and pos <

Tags: php, strpos

Is there a way to combine

```
 if ((strpos($str,"abc") !== false) and (strpos($str,"abc") < 1000))
```

Or do I need two ifs for that?
Because if abc isn't in the string the position is -1 so smaller than 1000.

I am only interested if php have some special for this problem ;)

Is this:

```
if (strpos(substr($str,0,1000),"abc") !== false)
```

a good way for it?

Comment: Yea.. considering it's `&&` not `and`. it should be fine =)

Comment: my example is working, but I want to have sth. shorter ;) I would like to delete the "and"

Comment: also, don't call the function twice, use a variable

Comment: Doc says `Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.`. So you won't get `-1`.

Comment: 'and' is actually valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Comment: @MackieeE  `and` is valid operator. http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @dragoste This didn't know and actually quite surprised.. :| (Still I'd *never* use it.)

Comment: I think I will use this: if (strpos(substr($str,0,1000),"abc") !== false)

Comment: `if ((($p = strpos($str,"abc")) !== false) && ($p < 1000))`

Comment: @MarkBaker: assignation inside an if like that is really not good a good habit to take for clarity. "Did you mean to assign, or is it a typo while you meant a comparison ?". I understand you answered the question, but this should be avoided.

Comment: @Lepidosteus - I agree with you about clarity, and won't generally use that type of syntax either; though I still don't really understand the OPs issue other than that he wants fewer characters in his line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pos_abc = strpos($str, 'abc');
if ($pos_abc !== false && $pos_abc < 1000)
```

You want to test two different things: 1- is `abc` in the string ? and 2- is `abc` in the first thousand characters of that string.
While it is possible to rewrite it in a single test, it provides no benefit, and it would actually costs a lot of clarity in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you want:

```
if( in_array(strpos($str,"abc"),range(0,1000),true))
```

However it doesn't look any simpler and it comes at a quite severe performance cost.

Perhaps the best way would be to use a variable:

```
$pos = strpos($str,"abc");
if( $pos !== false && $pos < 1000) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

two issues:

- your double strpos
- the comparison (2. and operator) depends on the first, which may cause issues (eg. in later php versions)

UPDATE:

the nice and quick solution pattern:

```
if(($pos = strpos($str,"abc") !== false)?($pos < 1000):false)
```

the nice and clean solution pattern:

```
$pos = strpos($str,"abc");
if(($pos !== false)?($pos < 1000):false)
```

Comment: assignation inside an if like that is really not good a good habit to take for clarity. "Did you mean to assign, or is it a typo while you meant a comparison ?". I understand you answered the question, but this should be avoided. This solution is anything but "nice and clean"