# What is the difference between code

Tags: php, operators

I have the following lines of code in PHP:

```
$a = $b && $c || $d;
```

and

```
$a = $b AND $c || $d;
```

and

```
$a = $b && $c OR $d;
```

and

```
$a = $b AND $c OR $d;
```

Every line uses different operators, so is it different and if it is, what is the difference?
How is it executed?

Comment: The different forms have different precedence.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in order how those operators are executed.

[Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

```
// The result of the expression (true && false) is assigned to $g
// Acts like: ($g = (true && false))
$g = true && false;

// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is Operator Precedence:

[image]

For more info:https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

As `short-circuit, they are the same.`&&`means`And`,`||`means`Or`, they act the same:

```
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit
$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

In the other side, `||` has a greater precedence than `or`,

```
// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

The same to `&&` and `and`:

```
// The result of the expression (true && false) is assigned to $g
// Acts like: ($g = (true && false))
$g = true && false;

// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```