# Can't figure out why this function returns NULL

Tags: php, recursion

EDIT: Sorry I didn't make this more clear. Replace "Echo" with "return" in front of "hi" and it returns null. I'm just showing that I can get inside that conditional.

This PHP function is supposed to calculate a sum of values passed from a database into an array. The function needs to be able to accept multiple columns (array) of values, and return an array of their summed values.

Below: $val is the column name and $result is the data returned from the query. So the data needs to be matched up with the correct keys (help by $val). As you can see I tried adding some checks to make sure the function is returning at the correct time. Echoing the variable shows that I am reaching that point, ("hi" is echoed) but it always returns NULL. Please feel free to ask questions if this is not clear enough.

```
function getSum($val,$result,$i=1,$count)
{
    $sum = array();
    if(is_array($val) == true)
    {
        foreach($val as $henh)
        {
            //echo $i;
            $this->getSum($henh,$result,$i,$count);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $strs = explode('.',$val);
        $str = $this->getParameters(array($strs[1]));
        //var_dump($str[$strs[1]]); exit;
        if($str[$strs[1]]['Parameter']['type']=='int' || $str[$strs[1]]['Parameter']['type']=='float')
        {
            //echo $i;
            $c = true;
            foreach($result as $item)
            {
                foreach($item as $k=>$v)
                {
                    if($k==$val AND $v !== null)
                    {
                        $c = true;
                        $sum[$val][] =  intval($v);
                    }
                }
            }
            if($i==$count AND isset($sum[$val]) !== 0)
            {
                echo "hi!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `if(is_array($val) == true)` just do `if (is_array($val))`...

Comment: cuz you are not returning any thing .

Comment: @ImadOS replace "echo 'hi'" with return "hi" and it returns null

Comment: @Axschech this mean that if($i==$count AND isset($sum[$val]) !== 0) is false

Comment: It's not, because that echos. The string "hi" is echoed correctly. replace it with "return hi" and it returns null

Comment: Do you understand the problem now? I can reach that point successfully, and "hi" gets echoed, but it always returns null.

Comment: Yeah, we understand. `echo` is not `return`. Functions don't return what's `echo`ed inside of them, they return what's `return`ed in them.

Comment: @Axschech can you pls check if you get in at this point  $sum[$val][] =  intval($v); . put an echo "test1";

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I don't think you are understanding. If I can echo "hi" from within that if statement, why can't I return "hi"?

Comment: yes, I've tested that. The array builds just fine.

Comment: can you provide the calling line of that method pls

Comment: I can't provide any information about the data itself, but the call is the same as it is inside the is_array check. its just a class function call.

Comment: i meant $this->getSum($henh,$result,$i,$count); .you didn't keep the returned results

Comment: all it is supposed to is recurse until it finds a value that is not an array, which is then passes to the function to use.

Comment: @Axschech See my answer. You are calling your function recursively, but you are not returning values recursively.

Answer (score 2):

There is no return statement in the function so it will not return anything, ever.

Comment: Your example is missing last curly bracket, it is calling functions we know nothing about and it is still missing the return statement. And `isset($sum[$val]) !== 0` makes no sense at all because it will always be true since you are comapring wheter true or false (return values from isset()) is not the same as 0.

Comment: It's isset($sum... AND $sum[$val] !== 0... no, $sum[$val] is not always set, that's what the loop inside the second half of the function does. All that one function does is pull in the datatype based off the name of the column in order to check it. I thought that was obvious. Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to say?

Comment: By far the biggest problem is that you dont have return statement anywhere in the function. Way smaller problem is the isset() thing. But about that smaller issue, `isset($sum[$val])` will always return `true` or `false`. Then you compare that are `true` or `false` different than `0`. Since true or false are not same as 0, the whole comparison is always true, so it does not do anything.

Comment: did you look at my edit? it's supposed to return "hi" instead of echo it

Comment: Yes I've read your edits but please keep the code example current. Since your example contains really basic mistakes, it is better that we don't guess what you have tried, but you actually provide the real example that you have tried.

Comment: I clearly pointed out where the problem was, especially after the edit. Any suggestions towards solving that problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you aren't returning anything. There is no return statement anywhere in your function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0):

If you read the note on the PHP documentation, your function will return `NULL` if no return value is specified:

> Note: If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned.

So, a function, will in fact return. But it will return `NULL`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

In addition to that, your syntax looks wrong for the `if`:

```
if($i==$count AND isset($sum[$val]) !== 0)
```

In PHP, the `!==` (triple inequality) operator will not use type coercion, so you are comparing the return value of `isset()` which returns type `bool` to `0`. Also, `AND` is strange in PHP. It has a lower precedence than `&&` and [can lead to some weird output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator), if you're doing variable assignment, so I would recommend using `&&` unless you intend to have lower precedence.

Your `if` should look something like:

```
if($i == $count && isset($sum[$val]) && $sum[$val] !== 0)
```

Lastly, you are calling your function recursively, but you are not *returning* the values recursively.

This:

```
 $this->getSum($henh,$result,$i,$count);
```

Should be like this:

```
 return $this->getSum($henh,$result,$i,$count);
```

Comment: @Axschech I made an edit, in response to your update.

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything.

Comment: in php boolean is 1 and 0 . but isset returns 1 and null , i

Comment: @ImadOS In his `if` he is not comparing the value of the `$sum` variable. He is comparing with the return value of `isset`.

Comment: ik , but you did , you can check if it's an number  .

Comment: i think this if($i == $count && isset($sum[$val])) is enough .what you think ?

Comment: adding return in front of it does nothing

Comment: @Axschech Yes. I was asking if you added it to **both** places because that is essential for you to pass the return value back up the recursion tree.

Comment: @Axschech You need to edit your question and give a desired input and output.

Comment: The input is private. I've already answered this request. I've clearly explained what kind of input the function should be able to accept and output. I appreciate your attempt at help, though, thanks!