# how to use the operators AND, OR in the IF statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I tried to use the operators AND, OR in an IF statement in a PHP script like this:

```
if($user[id]=='1' AND (($_GET['f']=='f-ppas') || ($_GET['f']=='f-kua'))){
   .....
}
```

But the result is wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Define "wrong". PS: it's weird you're using `AND` together with `||` (instead of `OR`) in the same expression - looks inconsistent

Comment: Use `&&` in place of `AND`

Comment: `$user[id]` will cause a PHP notice if it doesn't have `'` around the key. Should be `$user['id']`

Comment: I don't know what you expected, but as you use `A AND (B OR C)` this evaluates to `(A AND B) OR (A AND C)`. Maybe not what you expected.

Comment: @zerkms I dont think so. I do not think it is not a problem using a statement like that.

Comment: @responsiblevebri: I didn't say it's a *problem*. I said it looks *inconsistent*.

Comment: What about: `if(($user['id'] == 1) && (($_GET['f'] == 'f-ppas') || ($_GET['f'] == 'f-kua'))) {}`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but the result is wrong

Comment: You have a capital (AND), its should be small (and)

Comment: It Seems you have too many brackets try this --- if ($user[id] == '1' && $_GET['f'] == 'f-ppas' || $_GET['f'] == 'f-kua' ){
   .....
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `AND` to `&&`

```
if($user['id']=='1' && (($_GET['f']=='f-ppas') || ($_GET['f']=='f-kua'))){
   .....
}
```

The `AND` operator has some precedence problems.

```
$this = true;
$that = false;

$truthiness = $this and $that;
```

`$truthiness` above has the value `true`. Why? `=` has a higher precedence than and. The addition of parentheses to show the implicit order makes this clearer:

```
 ($truthiness = $this) and $that
```

If you used `&&` instead of `and` in the first code example, it would work as expected and be false.

Reference: ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Comment: Then you have problems with the logic of the IF statement. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. update your question so we could answer it correctly :)

Comment: Yes it will work but in some cases like what i stated in my examples, the `AND` Operator has precedence problems.

Comment: It's quite unfair to tell that operator has some precedence problems. It's not. The precedence is well defined. So it's a programmer who uses an operator without checking its precedence who has some problems.

Comment: Okay, wrong choice of word. The `AND` operator if used carelessly, it will generate the wrong output. :p