# '&&' and 'AND' is different in PHP

Tags: php

```
$A = True;
$B = False;
$C = $A AND $B;
$D = $A && $B;

echo 'C='.$C.'<br/>';
echo 'D='.$D.'<br/>';
```

Output:
C=1
D=

Or I missing something?

Comment: They also have different precedences. Check the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 7):

`AND` has lower precedence.

`$C = $A AND $B` will be parsed as `($C = $A) AND $B`.

Answer (score 1):

For variables $a and $b set as follows:

```
<?php

$a = 7;
$b = 0;
```

the advantage of using `AND` is short-circuit evaluation that occurs in code like the following:

```
$c = $a AND $b;
var_dump( $c ); // 7
```

Since the assignment operator has higher precedence than AND, the value of $a  gets assigned to $c; $b gets skipped over.

Consider the following code in contrast:

```
<?php

$c = $a && $b;
var_dump( $c ); // (bool) false
```

In this snippet, `&&` has a higher precedence than the assignment operator, and given the value of $a being non-zero, there is no short-circuiting. The result of this logical AND is based on the evaluation of *both* $a and $b.  $a evaluates as true and $b as false. The overall value of the expression, false, is what gets assigned to $c.  This result is quite different than in the prior example.

Comment: Okay I see.
I didn't see asignment operator included in short-circuiting.
Thank you for all that answered, the case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

both have same thing, but `&&` has higher precedence than `AND.`

for more:- ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test logic values use `var_dump()`. Like this:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($a AND $b);
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump($a && $b);
echo '</pre>'
```

Answer (score -1):

D is the correct output.

PHP doesn't echo false values, but if you did `var_dump($D);` then you should see that the value is `false`.

You should use `&&` when trying to do boolean operations.

Comment: You can't assing vardup with concatenation to strings. It returns nothing.

Comment: Corrected, one of those stupid things that we forget. It still printed, it was just out of order.

Comment: PHP _does_ echo falsy values, you just don't see it. If `false` (or `null`) are converted to a string, the result is an empty string (`var_dump((string) false);`)

Comment: @ Elias Van Ootegem actually PHP prints nothing at all when false is in a string context.  Internally PHP optimizes away the empty strings by having the function responsible for creating printable output return 0 when an empty string results; see http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend.c#322