# PHP xor returns wrong value

Tags: php, xor

Using php 7.1.0 I'm running this little test:

```php
<?php

$a = true;
$b = true;

$value = $a xor $b;
if ($value == true) {
    print "bad!\n";
} else {
    print "good\n";
}
```

and it's coming back and saying bad.  Why?  An xor of two true values should be FALSE, not true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence. The `xor` operator has lower precedence than `=`, so your statement is equivalent to:

```
($value = $a) xor $b;
```

You need to write:

```
$value = ($a xor $b);
```

or

```
$value = $a ^ $b;
```

The `^` operator is bit-wise XOR, not boolean. But `true` and `false` will be converted to `1` and `0`, and the bit-wise results will be equivalent to the boolean results. But this won't work if the original values of the variables could be numbers -- all non-zero numbers are truthy, but when you perform bit-wise XOR with them you'll get a truthy result for any two numbers that are different.

See the [PHP Operator Precedence Table](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php)

See the related [Assignment in PHP with bool expression: strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032947/assignment-in-php-with-bool-expression-strange-behaviour/29032948?s=5|0.0000#29032948)

Comment: @Gargoyle It was presumably done for consistency with `and` and `or`. The difference is that there are also `&&` and `||` variants of them, which have higher precedence, but there's no high-precedence variant of `xor`.

Comment: @PaulCrovella `^` is binary XOR, not boolean.

Comment: And XOR can't do short-circuiting. That's the other difference between the boolean and binary operators, but irrelevant for XOR.

Comment: If it is guaranteed that `$a` and `$b` are both Boolean values, `$value = $a != $b` would also work (or even `$value = $a !== $b`).