# How about method of var_dump($x) in php

Tags: php, character

By the way i surprised about this 
What will this code output and why?

```
$x = true and false;
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: *What will this code output and why?* Why not just try it?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surprisingly to many, the above code will output bool(true) seeming to imply that the `and` operator is behaving instead as an `or`.

The issue here is that the = operator takes precedence over the and operator in order of operations, so the statement `$x = true` and false ends up being functionally equivalent to:

`$x = true;`      // sets $x equal to true
true and false;  // results in false, but has no affect on anything
This is, incidentally, a great example of why using parentheses to clearly specify your intent is generally a good practice, in any language. For example, if the above statement `$x = true` and false were replaced with `$x = (true and false)`, then `$x` would be set to false as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator), the `=` operator has higher precedence than the `and` operator, causing `$x = true` to evaluate before `true and false` does, meaning that `$x` will take the value of `true`.

This will give you what you want:

```
$x = (true and false);
```