# How do I use or operator in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($a=="" and $b=="" or $c=="") {
    echo "something";
}
```

I want to ask that if `$a` AND `$b` is empty then it will print: `something`. But  if `$b` is not empty, then it will check the statement like this e.g. if `$a` is empty AND `$c` is empty then print: `something` (Means `$a` is compulsory to check with the variable which is empty `$b` OR `$c`)

Comment: @Rizier123 This isn't about using the spelled out names versus the operators. This question relates to precedence between `and` and `or`. He'd have the same problem if he used `&&` and `||`, he would still need parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar your right, my fault. I was too quick then.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

See the PHP [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) table. `and` has higher precedence than `or`, so your condition is treated as if you'd written

```
if (($a == "" and $b == "") or ($c == ""))
```

Since you want the `$a` check to be independent, you need to use parentheses to force different grouping:

```
if ($a == "" and ($b == "" or $c == ""))
```

Note that in expressions, it's conventional to use `&&` and `||` rather than `and` and `or` -- the latter are usually used in assignments as a control structure, because they have lower precedence than assignments. E.g.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

See ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Just force the comparison order/precedence by using parentheses:

```
if( $a == "" and ( $b == "" or $c == "" ) )
```

But you would be better off using `&&` and `||`:

```
if( $a == "" && ( $b == "" || $c == "" ) )
```

Comment: I'd say this does _not_ implement the described logic.

Comment: @arkascha: And you can describe the logic based on _MEANS $a IS COMPULSORY TO CHECK WITH THE VARIABLE WHICH IS EMPTY $b or $c_

Comment: Sorry, but this would also resolve to `true` if `$a` is _not_ empty, but `$c` is.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
if (
    ($a == '')
    &&
    (
        ($b == '')
        ||
        ($c == '')
    )
   )
```

so, it will print `something` only when $a is empty and either $b or $c empty

Comment: I would call this "questionable indentation" :-) However the logic is correct.

Comment: @arkascha indentation is only to show logic and priorities