# Unable to use AND to replace && in a PHP ternary operator condition

Tags: php

[update]
This isn't a duplicate question of "what's the difference between AND and &&" rather it's a question regarding the use of AND and the ternary operator. anyway i think i got my answer i didn't know that all operators have precedence which alex kindly pointed out. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

[original]

```
    echo TRUE && TRUE ? 'A' : 'B';
    // Outputs: A

    echo TRUE AND TRUE ? 'A' : 'B';
    // Outputs: 1
```

I know that the ternary operator syntax is

```
    condition ? true : false
```

and the difference between && and AND is evaluation precedence (of the condition)

e.g. TRUE AND TRUE && TRUE is evaluated at (TRUE AND (TRUE && TRUE))

so shouldn't using both AND and && yield the same return? is this a PHP bug? (im using ver5.5.23)

or should i just accept the fact that if i used AND in the condition it actually becomes excluded from the condition

e.g.
TRUE AND TRUE ? 'A' : 'B' => (TRUE AND (TRUE ? 'A' : 'B'))

Comment: Yes, there is. `&&` has precedent over `AND` same goes for `||` and `OR`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Comment: you're missing brackets `echo (true and true)  ? 'A' : 'B';`  will always output A though since its not a proper conditional

Comment: i know && has precedence over AND but that's not the problem here... the problem is that the ternary operator itself has precedence over the AND, which to me is weird.

Comment: i know it will work if we put bracket to correct this... but the question is why when brackets are omitted the behaviour is not as expected.

Comment: You have `echo (TRUE && TRUE) ? 'A' : 'B';` and `echo TRUE AND (TRUE ? 'A' : 'B');`, if that helps.