# Valid syntax in PHP for different

Tags: php

Is this a valid syntax in php? I want a call to be done if these two conditions are met.

```
if($valuear[$i] < $rake) and ($winuser != $winar[$i])
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing the opening and closing bracket for your if statment , else it is okay

Comment: `and` may not work as you expect it to, it is not the same as `&&` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't

```
if (($valuear[$i] < $rake) && ($winuser != $winar[$i]) ){}
```

You must wrap the whole condition in brackets.

This could help you:

and : &&

or  : ||

Comment: You could also use the words `and` and `or`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @tino.codes you could but `and` and `or` have lower operator precedence so you may not get what you're expecting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Comment: @CD001 As a programmer you should know the difference between a _comparison operator_ (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) an a _logical operator_ (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). So the operator precedence is absolutly clear (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Simple rule: _Comparison_ before _Logic_ (execpt the `!` ;) ).

Comment: @tino.codes I'm not arguing the point - you're obviously aware of the difference... the same cannot be said of everyone on SO - so I'd tend to err on the side of caution. Yes you can use `and` and `or` **but** you need to know when not to - I've never run into a use case with PHP where `&&` and `||` don't get the desired result.

Comment: @CD001 You only get into trouble when you mix it (use `and` and `&&` or `or` and `||`). Than it's hard to understand (for beginners) wich operator has the higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid way :

```
if($valuear[$i] < $rake && $winuser != $winar[$i])
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your answer to make yourself clear ? Written this way, one can think that the code you provide is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Set the brackets in this way:

```
if($valuear[$i] < $rake and $winuser != $winar[$i])
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

The basic syntax is:

```
if (expr)
  statement
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get syntax error for what you have done

```
if($valuear[$i] < $rake) and ($winuser != $winar[$i])
```

It should be

```
if(($valuear[$i] < $rake) and ($winuser != $winar[$i]))
  ^                                                   ^
```