# Google App Engine gives me 'Undefined index' errors, that are not there in the local enviroment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

In theory I know what is causing the errors my question is more if what I'm doing is acctually that wrong or if google app engine is just printing errors that are not that important.

So the code that causes the error:

```
$test = isValid($_GET["id"])

function isValid($var) {
    return isset($var) AND $var != "";
}
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /base/data/home/apps/somestuff/1.892737377923487/result.php on line 3
```

So the error says that the index `id` is undefined, which in some cases it is but I want to check if it is set and if it is not empty, because the form that sends this data sends empty strings in some of the fields so the `isset()` returns `true` but it is not valid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth checking out variable scoping in PHP to get a handle on why this error is coming up. There are three variables operating in the piece of code above.

In the first line, you set `$test` to be the returned value of the `isValid()` function, to which you provide the value of `$_GET["id"]` as an argument. When there is no `$_GET[]` variable provided with the name `id`, however, PHP throws a `Notice` saying exactly that - that the index `is` is undefined - but since this is just a notice, and your error reporting is set to tolerate notices, the script just carrys on, and assumes the value of `$_GET["id"]` to be empty (i.e., `""` == `false` == `0` == `null` etc.).

In the `isValid()` function, you have a new variable defined (`$var`) which is local in its scope, existing *only inside the function.* Thus, `$var` will always be defined inside this function, and thus `isset($var)`, inside the function, will always be `true`. Even when `$_GET["id"]` is empty, `$var` will still be defined with the empty value PHP automatically gave to it.

If you wanted to determine whether `$_GET["id"]` exists, you would have to use the `isset()` function on this variable, not a locally scoped variable which has been assigned with its value (or lack thereof). Thus, you could get rid of the notice, and have the same effect as before, by using this line of code:

```
$test = (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"]));
```

Hope this helps, I think the link below might help you out!

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks! I just notice how stupid my function is. Also is `&&` in some way better than `AND`?

Comment: Yep, `&&` and `||` have higher precedence than `and` and `or`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator