# Problems with Empty Strings. Empty() not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a form that'll create a Word doc. There's a part where the user will create a list, and will separete the list lines by using the **" | "** (vertical bar) as a delimeter. I'm trying to **explode()** a string like this: **"First line| Second line| Third and last line |"**. As you guys saw, I placed a vertival bar delimiter after the last line, that's 'cause the user will probably do this mistake, and it will generate a empty line on the list.
I'm trying to avoid this error by using something like this:

```
$lines = explode("|",$lines);
for($a=0;$a<count($lines);$a++)
{
  if(!empty($lines[$a]) or !ctype_space($lines[$a])) 
  {
    //generate the line inside de Word Doc
  }
}
```

This code works when I create the string by my own while testing the code, but won't work when the string come from a Form. And keep generating a empty line list inside the Word Doc.
When I **var_dump()** the **$lines** array it shows the last key as: **[2]=> string(0) ""**

I'm using Laravel and the form was created with the Form:: facade.(don't know if this matter, prob not)

If you guys could help me, I'd apreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use PHP's `&&` (and) rather than `or`.
For reference, see [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

You only want to output the line if *both* `empty()` and `ctype_space()` return false. With your current code, blank strings will pass your `if` test because `ctype_space()` returns false even though `empty()` does not. Strings made up entirely of spaces will also pass because `empty()` returns false even though `ctype_space()` does not.

To correct the logic:

```
if(!empty($lines[$a]) && !ctype_space($lines[$a])) { ... }
```

---

Alternatively, I'd suggest trimming white space from the string before checking `empty()`:

```php
$lines = explode("|",$lines);

if (!empty($lines)) {
  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!empty(trim($line)) {
      // output this line
    }
  }
}
```

Also, see ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator).

Comment: The [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133160/problems-with-empty-strings-empty-not-working#answer-38133591) from @Progrock is even more sleek ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively just use array_filter with the callback of trim to remove elements that are empty or contain spaces before you iterate.

```
<?php
$string = '|foo|bar|baz|bat|';
$split  = explode('|', $string);
$split  = array_filter($split, 'trim');
var_export($split);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'foo',
  2 => 'bar',
  3 => 'baz',
  4 => 'bat',
)
```

However you might not want to remove some empty values!

You could just trim off your pipes to begin with:

```
<?php
$string = '|foo|bar|baz|bat|';
$string = trim($string, '|');
$split  = explode('|', $string);
var_export($split);
```

Output as above.

Or use `rtrim`.

Comment: Beautiful. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) callback is a very useful piece of code.