# how to create condition in php with and / or

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a condition in php for this situation:

You can choose for a radio input or checkbox input. 
No matter what you choose, but if you choose one of them, it may not be empty.

```
$quickpolltype = "radio"; // set to "radio" or "checkbox"; radio is one choice, checkbox is multiple choices
```

I have seperated the 2 conditions now like below:

```
if($quickpolltype == "radio" and $_POST['radiovote'] != '') {
// do something
}
if($quickpolltype == "checkbox" and $_POST['checkboxvote'] != '') {
// do something
}
```

what i want to achieve:

No matter what you choose as type in `$quickpolltype`, if the value of one of them is not empty --> do something

So how can i combine those 2 conditions in 1 condition, whatever quickpolltype is choosen?

Comment: if the value doesn't matter, then don't test it? `if(radiovote != '' && checkboxvote != '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it is advisable to use `&&` and `||` see here ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Also you are doing an assignment `=` and not a comparison `==`.

So you want something like:

```
if($quickpolltype == "radio" && $_POST['radiovote'] != '') {
    // do something
}
if($quickpolltype == "checkbox" && $_POST['checkboxvote'] != '') {
    // do something
}
```

Essentially you were making `$quickpolltype` `"radio"` rather then checking if it was equal to it. Same for `"checkbox"`.

To make all of that in one `if`

```
if(($quickpolltype == "radio" && $_POST['radiovote'] != '') 
    || ($quickpolltype == "checkbox" && $_POST['checkboxvote'] != '')){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: you are right @nerdlyist. it should be a comparison instead of assignment. But how can i combine these 2 conditions into 1?

Comment: @JackMaessen assuming that the same thing should happen in either of the `if` statements the edits should do it.

Comment: That's the one i need! Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 3):

If the "do something" is going to be the same, you can certainly combine the two conditions. If not, keep them separate.

```
if(($quickpolltype=="radio" && $_POST['radiovote'] != '') || ($quickpolltype="checkbox" && $_POST['checkboxvote'] != '')) {
    //do something
}
```

Make sure that when comparing things in PHP, you are using "=="! Additionally, you may want to be [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator) of using "and" and "or" instead of "&&" and "||" in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons and Checkboxes are tricky beasts because if you select nothing then their `name="radiovote"` will never make it to be available in `$_POST['radiovote']` so you need the power of [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Also make sure to use the appropriate `&&` or `||` operators

```
if(
    in_array($quickpolltype, array("radio","checkbox")) &&
    (
        (isset($_POST['radiovote']) && $_POST['radiovote'] != '') ||
        (isset($_POST['checkboxvote']) && $_POST['checkboxvote'] != '')
    )
  )
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is semantically different from what the question asked for. It will `Do something` when `$quickpolltype == "radio"` even if `$_POST['radiovote'] == ''`, as long as `$_POST['checkboxvote'] != ''`.