# How to find if a variable is isset and its value equals somthing?

Tags: php, if-statement

I know it is already asked few time in this forum but i can't get my answer properly.

I have a variable let it be `$val` i want to check if it is isset and if it's value is equals to 'something'.

```
if(isset($val) and $val == "something")
{
Do Something ...
}
else
{
Do Another Thing...
}
```

Note $val is not array, it is a variable. I got a question like this where $val was array.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Use `&&` not `and` even though 'and' *will work*. [PHP Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) which leads me to believe this question is about something else.

Comment: if(isset($val) && $val == "something"){}

Comment: yes you can check it like `if(isset($val) && $val == "something")`

Comment: Thanks, but how it works by && operator?

Comment: This could easily be answered with a search engine. No need for stack overflow

Comment: and `$val` is what exactly? not "Something" I hope, or `something ` with a space. We've no way of knowing what the variable really is

Comment: here you can read the documentation http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/logical-operators.php

Comment: @JYoThI why not use the real docs at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: and the mystery continues. Well, you have answers below; ask them. I'll take my "back seat" out of here, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `&&` operator

```
 if(isset($val) && $val == "something")
    {
    Do Something ...
    }
    else
    {
    Do Another Thing...
    }
```

for AND vs && you can refer this

['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Comment: [Not true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) see this [example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ehcj-3nv0)

Comment: @JayBlanchard.yes you are right.Thanks for the correction

Comment: I'd add an `|| == "Something" || == "something " || == "somthing"` *lol*. I think the OP isn't telling us the full story, right @JayBlanchard ? Just as you said in a comment up there. I'll be in the Lizard Lounge soon; having morning sunrise coffee ;-)

Comment: Right @Fred-ii- ! See you in the lounge!

Answer (score 2):

just use `&&`  [logical operators](http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/logical-operators.php)

The standard logical operators and, or, not and xor are supported by PHP. Logical operators first convert their operands to boolean values and then perform the respective comparison.

```
if(isset($val) && $val == "something"){ }
```

I tested this one it's also working fine

```
if(isset($val) and $val == "something"){ }
```