# php logical operator 'or' between different data types

Tags: php

```
<?php

 $sample = (False or 436);
 echo $sample;
?>
```

I tried this code to identify and have and idea about how operator precedence effects to code. But I'm totally confusing with the answers I got.

```
 <?php

 $sample = (False or 436);
 echo $sample;
?>
```

gives answer as `1`

```
<?php

 $sample = (True or 436);
 echo $sample;
?>
```

gives `1` too

```
 <?php

 $sample = False or 436;
 echo $sample;
?>
```

gives nothing.

As I could see whatever I put next to the `or` the answer was `1`

P.S. I tried them on `http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/` this online editor.

I need to know the is the actual concept behind it.

Comment: See [this post:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator#2803576). In short:  = has a higher precedence than and. The addition of parentheses to show the implicit order makes this clearer:

Comment: @ mseifert why I got '1' then? Is it reference to something?

Comment: Fine. I got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the answers I got I could find all in one answer for what I posted. I think this may be helpful.

```
 <?php 
  $var1 = TRUE; 
  $var2 = FALSE; 
  $var3 = 123;


  $x = (int)$var2 or $var3;
  echo $x;// $x assigned to $var2 and type cast into int-display 0

  $y = ($var2 or $var3);
  echo $y;//operation inside the () returns true. so it prints 1

  $n = ($var2 or $var2);
  echo $n;//operation inside the () returns false.It concider as NULL. display nothing
  echo (int)$n;//print numerical value for false-0

  $z = $var2;
  echo $z;//returns 0. It is considered as NULL. so display nothing

 ?>
```

This is the exact answer I really expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is something called operator precedence. If you remove the brackets, the assignment `$sample = false` takes precedence before the `or 436` function. The result is `echo false`, which outputs nothing. That is why you in most cases should use `||` operator instead.

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a read at [PHP Type Comparison Tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) as well as the [Booleans documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).  Pay special attention to Fred Koschara's notes in the top comment, which explains that the OR operator has lower precedence than the assignment operator.  You may instead be looking to use || instead of OR, as the || operator does the same thing, but with higher precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the references. It was known to me OR has the lowest precedence. But I didn't know why I got '1' as the result. I