# Why is the value of var_dump(true and false) as boolean(true)?

Tags: php, boolean, algebra

What I want to understand -

```
$x = true and false;

var_dump($x);
```

Answer comes out to be as boolean(true);

But under algebra i have been learning as 1 and 0 is 0

Ran the code in php

Comment: it must be `&&`

Comment: Actually, `var_dump(true and false)`, as posed in the title, *is* `false`. That's not the same operation as `$x = true and false`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`and` has a lower [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=` so what you are executing is:

```
($x = true) and false;
```

So the complete expression - which you don't use the result of - will return `false`, but `$x` will be `true`.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the `and` operator does not work as you think: ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Basically, `=` has higher precedence.

```
$x = false && true;
var_dump($x);
```

returns `bool(false)`.

As does

```
$x = (false and true);
```