# How to use portion of an array in loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = "string";
$array[1] = "string1";
$array[2] = "string2";
$array[3] = "string3";
...
$array[99] = "string99";
$array[100] = "string100";
```

If I want to work with all the values of the array:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Depending on a condition, I might need to work with only portion of the array (for example 50-100). How do I extract key 50-100 from the array?

There is this way but it doesn't seem much efficient:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key > 49)
    {
        // Do something with the value
    }
}
```

Are there any better, more-efficient ways to do it?

Comment: You can use for loop with fixed indexes

Comment: @patryk-uszynski Can you show any examples?

Comment: The answers from patryk-uszynski, NN, and arkascha will all work, but I thing patryk-uszynski's is best for this example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array in your question has numerical indexes, so you can use `for` loop. Then only keys in specified range will be processed. When you are using `foreach` all elements will be.

**Example for range <50,100>**

```
for($i=50; $i<=100; $i++) {
    //do something with $array[$i]
}
```

All others key wont be processed. You can also use functions like `array_slice()`, but it wont be such efficient.

Answer (score 2):

PHP offers the function `array_slice()` for that:

An example using only the elements from key 50 upwards:

```
foreach (array_slice($array, 50) as $key => $value) {
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Using only 10 entries with an offset of 50, to elements 50-60:

```
foreach (array_slice($array, 50, 10) as $key => $value) {
    // Do something with the value
}
```

That function allows you to specify a length and an optional offset for the resulting part of the array.

See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0):

use array slice

```
 array_slice($array, 50, 100);
```

Comment: Welcome @TrondroMulligan

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key < 50 OR $key > 101)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't I still be looping through the 100 keys?

Comment: Yes because `foreach` as is said, always will be iterating throught all elements of array.

Comment: If you want to loop only those values then you should   use like this
 array_slice($array, 50, 100);

Comment: @YasarArafath be very careful with using `OR`. It might not behave the way you think it does. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator for details. While in your answer it will work. If you're assigning values it could go really messy.