# PHP Contact Form Failing

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

I'm wondering what is going wrong in this contact form. I'm not sure why, but it constantly defaults to the `else` and says `Something went wrong, please try again later.` I can't figure out why, and the error_log isn't showing anything. Is there anything glaringly obvious I'm missing? I'm pretty new to PHP.

PHP

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
    $from = 'From: HankSmith.com Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'thatbraxjohnsonguy@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'HANK SMITH CONTACT FORM';

    $body = "
            From: $name\n 
            E-Mail: $email\n 
            Phone: $phone\n
            Message: $message\n";

    if ($_POST['submit'] and $captcha == 4) {                
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p style="margin-top: 150; text-align:center; font-size: 18px;">Your message has been sent! Click <a href="../index.php">here</a> to return to the website.</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, try again later!</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

HTML Form

```
            <form class="contactform" method="post" action="php/contact.php">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <input class="form inputboxes" type="text" name="name">
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <input class="form inputboxes" type="text" name="email">
                <h3>Phone</h3>
                <input class="form inputboxes" type="text" name="phone">
                <h3>Message</h3>
                <textarea class="form inputboxes" name="message"></textarea>
                <h3 class="captchastyle">Are you real? What is 2 + 2?</h3><input class="captcha captchastyle" type="text" name="captcha" maxlength="1">
                <input class="form submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: may need  to see the form

Comment: I'll update the post with the form.

Comment: Post the html form.

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied this into my text editor, it threw a parse error because the echo statement in the if (mail)... section didn't have a closing brace. I never use 'and', I usually use '&&', but it actually doesn't seem to matter in this case.

```
if ($_POST['submit'] && $captcha == 4) {                
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p style="margin-top: 150; text-align:center; font-size: 18px;">Your message has been sent! Click <a href="../index.php">here</a> to return to the website.</p>';
        } // THIS MUST BE HERE
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, try again later!</p>'; 
    }
```

Also, you probably want an 'else' condition for that if (mail)... statement. If you're seeing a blank page, it will be because you aren't handling what happens if the mail() function returns false:

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
  echo '<p style="margin-top: 150; text-align:center; font-size: 18px;">Your message has been sent! Click <a href="../index.php">here</a> to return to the website.</p>';
} else {
  echo '<p>Problem sending mail!';
}
```

And honestly, the native PHP mail() function sucks! Consider using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead.

Comment: I forgot a brace?? Figures. Thanks. I'll test that out.

Comment: Okay so it didn't give me an error, just a blank page. Progress!

Comment: Yeah, it's actually not necessary since you only are running one statement in the if conditional. But, since you had an opening brace, the closing brace was necessary.

Comment: You are more than likely getting a blank page because the mail() function returned false, see my edit to my answer for a solution.

Comment: You're exactly right. Now it's throwing `Problem sending mail.` I'll edit the mail function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset` on your condition:

`if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $captcha == 4)`

It checks if the field is non empty and the form has been submitted.

And `&&` is better here than `and` see the reason here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861068

Comment: Still throws the same at me, I'm wondering if it's just the servers not propagating as fast as I'm updating.

Comment: Ok use `&&` and close the `}` as mentioned in next answer. It should work.

Comment: Well, instead of the error message I just got a blank page, so I consider that progress.

Comment: Now it kills the page haha. I'll keep trouble shooting!

Comment: No, I meant after answer from @daniel