# What is the purpose/function of `and` in PHP?

Tags: php

Searching for documentation on this is nigh-futile as search engines seem to assume I'm asking about the `&&` operand. What I found on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), touches on its use as an operand but I'm still unclear as to how it is working in a code snippet I ran across.

```
! empty( $foo )
    and $bar .= 'string';
```

I think I understand that to be something akin to:

```
if ( ! empty( $foo ) ){
    $bar .= 'string';
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be a bracket-less `if` conditional (it breaks if I remove the `and`).

I should say that I do – or thought I did – understand how `&&` an `and` would work in the context of a comparison. It is the use of it on its own line (partially) and that the `$bar .= 'string'` is not a test condition that prompted the question.

**Updated**

What I understand from the discussion in the comments is as follows:

If `! empty( $foo )` were to be `false`, it would short-circuit the operation; anything beyond the `and` would not be evaluated.

The `and` is still simply fulfilling its role as a comparison operator(?). In this usage, the `$bar .= 'string'` side of the `and` is not another test condition… or is it? Is it evaluating whether `$bar` is truthy (which, in PHP, it seems to be whether `$bar` was declared/defined beforehand or not), then continuing on to concatenate `string` to it?

Comment: Just like `&&` in an IF; the right hand expression won't be evaluated if the left hand expression is false.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Comment: Your first example is not a ternary. It has to be `some_variable = some_statement ? statement_is_true : statement_is_false;`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: [`$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) that's a ternary.

Comment: `if/else` is a _Control Structure_ and `and` is a _Logical Operator_.  Dont compare them in that way.

Comment: Depending on your point of view it's an idiomatic shorthand, or an abominable misuse of the operator over an `if`.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent `will evaluate both operands` Really?  `($false=false) and ($true=true);var_dump([$false,$true]);` or did i not understand it?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent I use this oftern for something like `DEBUG AND print 'Debugnote';` first is defined constant with true or false. Nice onliner that can simple removed or commented.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson (and Fred -ii-) Yep. "ternary" was not the term I should have used. Corrected. I think.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Why not `if (DEBUG) print 'Debugnote';`…?!

Comment: @deceze Someone will scream: The coding guide says that you should always you `{}` when using `if` ;--) And the `{` comes into the next line :-) And i can easy just remove or coment out lines that begin with `DEBUG AND` 8-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Quite honestly I'll scream even louder when `and` is abused this way; the real proper way to do this is something like `log(DEBUG, 'Debugnote')`.

Comment: @deceze php itself ist most of the time abused. :-) Im above screaming for a long time now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **short-circuit evaluation**. It can be understood more easily if you break it down:

```
!empty($foo)            // 1) expression
   and                  // 2) logical operator
      $bar .= 'string'; // 3) assignment, expression
```

1. `empty($foo)` will be evaluated, returning `true` or `false`, which will then be negated
2. `and` could as well be `&&`, it is a [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (the difference between the two is their [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/3316645))
3. `$bar .= 'string'` is an assignment and in PHP [those are expressions, too](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php). They evaluate to the assigned value, in this case some string. As long as that string isn't [empty or `"0"`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), it will evaluate to `true`.

Only if `!empty($foo)` yields `true` does PHP ever look at what comes after `and`:

```
! empty( $foo ) // If false, stop right here, otherwise...
    and $bar .= 'string'; // ...see what this evaluates to
```

Since in your example, the result of the whole expression is not used in any way, it does not matter what the string assignment evaluates to - the trick is simply to only execute it depending on `!empty($foo)`. Therefore, your `if` version indeed has the very same effect.

Now, why does this break when you remove `and`? Because then you end up with invalid PHP: `!empty($foo) $bar .= 'string';`

Slightly changing the original snippet, using `&&` instead of `and` and adding some brackets, make it a lot easier to read and understand:

```
!empty($foo) && ($bar .= 'string');
```

Also, this kind of shortcut is very common when using PHP with mysql. You have probably seen this line at one point or another:

```
mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die();
```

It is the same logic. If the connection can be established, `mysqli_connect()` returns an object (which evaluates to `true`) and the second part will never be looked at. If the connection fails, however, `die()` will be evaluated and script execution ends.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you! And now, when a n00b like me Googles "what is and in PHP?" they, hopefully, will see your answer.