# true & false as different than true and false if the latter is last - why?

Tags: php

If I understood Alena [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/logical-operators) correctly, she says that

```
$var1 = true && false;
$var2 = true and false;
```

Will produce in `var_dump($var1, $var2);`:

> false
>
> true

Alena also said that the above code is basically equal to:

```
$var1 = (true and false);
($var2 = true) and false;
```

I admit I failed to understand why the first example is euqal to the second. I mean, why writing the two rows, one above the other, will produce different outputs even though they seem equal in essence, thus should seemingly bring same outputs (**false, false**).

Comment: Read through this post to get good understanding of logical operators and their precedence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Comment: Because [PHP operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), that's why.

Comment: The question's title is misleading. In isolation, `$x && $y` is the same as `$x and $y`. The trouble starts when they are part of a larger expression.

Comment: @axiac your comment helped me to understand the principle, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because operator priority. For example, `1+2*3` is `1+(2*3)`.

Because `and` (which is actually `and or`) have less priority than `&&` and `||`, then, `=` is executed before `and`:

```
$bool = true and false
```