# Getting error message before entering text in textbox

Tags: php, preg-match, filter-validate-email

In below code I am getting error message `Sorry your name is not in correct format` even before I enter any text. Can anyone tell me what mistake am I making ?

```
if ((isset($_POST['name'])) and(isset($_POST['email'])) and (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) and (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/', $name))) {

    //if yes, it is writing it into file
    $myfile = fopen("names.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $name . "\r\n" . $email;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);

    fclose($myfile);
}
else {
    echo "Sorry, your name is not in correct format.";
}
```

Comment: Where is `$name` and `$email` defined? Turn on error-reporting and see what it spits out.

Comment: Well, if you haven't entered any text I assume you haven't submitted the form yet. If that's the case, then `isset($_POST['name'])` will be `false` (no form submission means no "name" field was posted) and you'll end up in your `else` condition.

Comment: $name and $email are like this $name = $email = " ";

Comment: So you're not setting it to the POST-values then? There's your issue.

Comment: I had it to POST value before but then I was getting error undefined index for $name and $email

Comment: Which indicates that you're not sending the proper values over POST. We're really not seeing enough to give you any further advice here. You need to show some more code and relevant errors.

Comment: Sidenote: `and` and `&&` are not necessarily the same thing. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2803321/1941241) and its answers for things to look out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate your condition in two `if` statements. The first to check if something was posted. The second to check if the input are valid. The `else` statement should go under the second `if` (if the input are not valid).

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) 
{
    $name = $_POST['name']; // get data from $_POST
    $email = $_POST['email']; // get data from $_POST
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/', $name))
    {
        //if yes, it is writing it into file
        $myfile = fopen("names.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = $name . "\r\n" . $email;
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, your name or email are not in correct format.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move the definition of `$email` and `$name` before the second condition, or it won't work.

Comment: Thank you @Syscall , I thought initially to do like that but I didn't and  thank you guys for your help and suggestions.