# Invert logical conditions or conditional statements

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I want to manually invert a logical condition.

Let's say we have this:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;

if (!$a or $b) {
    echo 'true';
}

if (!(!$a or $b)) { //I want to solve !(!$a or $b) to a form without ()
    echo 'true 2';
}
```

What are the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
!(A and B) == !A or !B
!(A or B)  == !A and !B
```

Therefore

```
!(!$a or $b) == !!$a and !$b == $a and !$b
```

You can also draw up an evaluation table:

```
$a     $b     !(!$a or $b)  $a and !$b
true   true   false         false
true   false  true          true
false  true   false         false
false  true   false         false
```

Side note:

Careful with `and`/`or` when you have assignments like `$val = true and false;`, cf. ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Answer (score 1):

So let say

`!(!$a or $b) === true` is the same as `!$a or $b === false`.

So `!$a or $b` must be false, which means `!$a` and `$b` should be both false, which in turn means `$a` must be true and `$b` must be false.

In the end, this `!(!$a or $b)` is equivalent to `$a and !$b`.

```
$a  $b  !(!$a or $b)   $a and !$b
T   T   F               F
T   F   T               T
F   T   F               F
F   F   F               F
```

We can also prove this using Boolean algebra and [De Morgan’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

¬(¬A∨B) = ¬(¬A)∧¬B = A∧¬B