# Trying to load separate headers for home, page, post, and category - only category doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Since I have different Google Ad Manager codes that need to load in the  of different content types, I created separate headers for each type and put this code snippet in index.php to load them accordingly:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) { 
    get_header('home') ;
}
elseif ( !is_front_page() AND is_page() ) {
    get_header('page') ;
}
elseif ( is_single() ) {
    get_header('article') ;
}
elseif ( is_category() ) {
    get_header('category') ;
}
else {
    get_header() ;
}
```

All of them work great - except for the category. It isn't loading. It just loads the default header.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be to try and use [`is_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) instead of [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/). If that doesn't work, you may need to dump your global `$wp_query` variable and see what query types are being returned on that particular url.

In that same vein, you may consider using [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) instead of [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/), because `is_single` is limited to Posts.

One more point to consider is using `&&` instead of `AND` (they're synonymous other than precedence. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/933810) for a bit more in-depth on it)

Lastly, if you're only loading in a separate Google Ad Manager code, I'm not sure you need to maintain `x` number of header files. Have you considered dropping in the script codes into your `functions.php` file and loading them on the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) or [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) hooks?

instead of maintaining separate headers like this:

```
if( is_front_page() ){
    get_header( 'home' );
} else if( is_page() ){
    get_header( 'page' );
} else if( is_singular() ){
    get_header( 'article' );
} else if( is_archive() ){
    get_header( 'category' );
} else {
    get_header();
}
```

You could drop those scripts straight in based on the same `is_` functions using something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'load_ad_manager_scripts' );
function load_ad_manager_scripts(){
    if( is_front_page() ){
        echo '<script>// Home Ad Manage Code</script>';
    } else if( is_page() ){
        echo '<script>// Page Ad Manage Code</script>';
    } else if( is_singular() ){
        echo '<script>// Single Manage Code</script>';
    } else if( is_archive() ){
        echo '<script>// Archive Manage Code</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script>// Generic Manage Code</script>';
    }
}
```