# What does the expression $a && $b = $a mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I am reading another person's code and here I saw something that I do not understand how to interpret it:

`$this->mobile && $content['mobile'] = $this->mobile;`

I have always seen && used as a logical operator between boolean expressions and on the right side of the assignment symbol. This seems pretty confusing to me and I couldn't find what it means on php.net.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

Comment: IMHO it's bad coding style, they are using it as a shortened `if` - so the value is only set if `$this->mobile` is *true*.

Comment: @NigelRen Oh, I see. So, if ``$this->mobile`` is set, the other expression (the assignment) after the logical operator is executed but if the first expression is not set, the assignment is ignored. Am I right?

Comment: Main thing is try it out (be careful what with *not being set* means)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$this->mobile && $content['mobile'] = $this->mobile;
```

means exactly the same thing as

```php
$this->mobile && ($content['mobile'] = $this->mobile);
```

Remember that in PHP, assignments are also expressions (they return values), and remember that `&&` evaluates the second expression only if there's a need for it, and in case of `false` first argument, there's no need, because the whole expression is `false`.

Being a developer myself, I can deduce that the initial intention of the author was to create a shorthand, for an if statement:

```php
if ($this->mobile) $content['mobile'] = $this->mobile;
```

which does the same thing.