# PHP : false OR false OR true == false?

Tags: php, variables, boolean, operator-precedence, boolean-logic

I don't understand what's going on here in PHP.
I've spent hours on this until I understood that it doen't work normally, or that I dont understand something.

Here the few lines :

```
$test = false OR false OR true;
echo $test;
```

Here $test is false, nothing is printed.
Also, if I try:

```
$test = false OR false OR true;
if($test){
    echo "IT'S TRUE";
}
```

Nothing is printed.

BUT HERE :

```
if(false OR false OR true){
    echo "IT'S TRUE";
}
```

"IT'S TRUE" is printed.

So the statement "false OR false OR true" is false when assigned to a variable, but true when is a condition.
Does anyone know and can explain to me why ?

EDIT : the answer was that :

```
$test = false OR false OR true;
```

is parsed like

```
($test = false) OR false OR true;
```

So I need to write :

```
$test = (false OR false OR true);
```

And it's work.
Thanks all !

Comment: Although it doesn't look like, this question is about the same thing as yours: ['AND' vs '&&' as operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator)

It's called "operator precedence" and explains, which operators are "binding" more to their operands. And `=` binds more than `and` or `or`.

Answer (score 3):

```php
$test = false OR false OR true;
```

Is actually parsed as:

```php
($test = false) OR false OR true;
```

Hence why the `$test` evaluates to `false` in your condition.

See here for more details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php