Why comparing 2 dates I got invalid results?
On laravel 10  site
I need to mark all tasks which are greater/equal today and less 3 days:
I do it with code :
        dump(  $today);    // 2024-07-15 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
        dump( '$task->deadline_at');
        dump( $task->deadline_at); // 2024-08-03 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)

        dump( '$task->deadline_at->gte($today)::');
        dump( $task->deadline_at->gte($today)); // outputed true - yes as expected

        dump( '$task->deadline_at->lt($today->addDays(3))::');
        dump( $task->deadline_at->lt($today->addDays(3))); // outputed false - yes as expected

        $less3days = ($task->deadline_at->gte($today)) and ($task->deadline_at->lt($today->addDays(3)));
        dump($task->id);
        dd($less3days); // But final result is TRUE - can not understand why - as I have "(true) and (false)" ?

Where is an error ?

You have an extra pair of parentheses. Your statement looks like (check1) AND (check2) instead of (check1 AND check2), so check1 is being assigned to the variable.

Maybe just use a simple way to compare the difference in days between two dates like "diffInDays()" (Carbon method) $task->deadline_at->diffInDays($today). There should not be a problem with "and" statement. The operator will evaluate the values if they are or not in parentheses.

You should also consider using && instead of and, for similar reasons to the issue pointed out by anyber above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

From a quick test, there is an issue using and here: https://i.sstatic.net/LIZhZodr.png; notice how the value of $less3Days changes depending on the usage of and vs &&.

Try changing that one line to be this:
$less3days = ($task->deadline_at->gte($today) && $task->deadline_at->lt($today->addDays(3)));


You don't need the outer (), simply $less3Days = $task->deadline_at->gte($today) && $task->deadline_at->lt($today->addDays(3));

Not and but && ? Looks like it works... Could you please to explain the difference?  I considered and is the same as  && ...

@PetroGromovo There are 3 comments below your question explaining why you should use && instead of and... && and and are not the same in PHP.

@TimLewis Let us redefine progress to mean that just because we can leave out parenthesis, it does not necessarily mean we must leave out parenthesis.

I have no idea what that comment is supposed to mean, but all I was saying is that you don't need the outer (). If you want to leave them in, that's fine, and in some cases, () usage does matter, but not here. It was simply a suggestion to make your code more concise, if you want to ignore that advice, that's perfectly fine.
