# Why do we use assert() and assert_options() in PHP?

Tags: php, assert, assertion

I am new to using PHP and am learning it by reading the documentation on **php.net**- currently the page for [assert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) to know about those **assert()** and **assert_options()** functions, but it does not explain *why* we use them and what these functions do in simple words. What do these functions and why do we use them in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I be using assert in my PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516419/should-i-be-using-assert-in-my-php-code)

Comment: Recommended viewing: [John Lakos' Talk *Defensive Programming Done Right*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QhtXRMp3Hg) on preconditions, asserts and defensive programming. While this is a C++ talk, the ideas apply to any programming language and John gives one of the most accurate descriptions of the topic that I know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Assert()` is a clever function that works along the same lines as our print statements, but they only have any effect if a certain condition is not matched. Essentially, `assert()` is used to say "This statement must be true - if it isn't, please tell me". Consider this following example:

```
<?php
    print "Stage 1\n";
    assert(1 == 1);
    print "Stage 2\n";
    assert(1 == 2);
    print "Stage 3\n";
?>
```

Here we have two `assert()`s, with the first call asserting that one must be equal to one, and the second call asserting that one must be equal to two. As it is impossible to redefine constants like 1 and 2, the first `assert()` will always evaluate to true, and the second will always evaluate to false. Here is the output from the script:

> Stage 1 Stage 2 Warning: assert()
>
> [http://www.php.net/function.assert]: Assertion failed in
>   /home/paul/sandbox/php/assert.php on line 5
>
> Stage 3

Note that the first `assert()` is not seen in the output at all because it evaluated to `true`, whereas the second `assert()` evaluated to `false`, so we get a `warning` about an `assertion failure`. Also note that we see `"Stage 3"` after the assertion `failure warning`, because the script carries on executing after the failure. As long as assertions evaluate to true, they have no effect on the running of the script, which means you can insert them for debugging purposes and not have to worry about taking them out once you are finished debugging.

---

If you are worried about your assertions slowing execution down, which, although the speed hit will be minimal, is still a valid concern, you can disable execution of `assert()` by using the `assert_options()` function or by setting `assert.active` to Off in your php.ini file. If you want to use `assert_options()`, it takes two parameters - the option to set and the value you wish to set it to - and there are a variety of ways it can make assert() more powerful.
[image]

Note that all of these options can be set in your `php.ini` file so that they are always in effect - the key options to change are `assert.active, assert.warning, assert.bail, assert.quiet_eval, and assert_callback`.

`ASSERT_CALLBACK` is a very useful options as it allows you to write an error handler for when your code fails an assertion. It takes the string name of a function to execute when assertions fail, and the function you define must take three parameters - one to hold the file where the assertion occurred, one to hold the line, and one to hold the expression. Using all three together in your callback function allows you to generate meaningful error messages that you can debug easily. Consider this code snippet:

```
<?php
    function assert_failed($file, $line, $expr) {
        print "Assertion failed in $file on line $line: $expr\n";
    }

    assert_options (ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'assert_failed');
    assert_options (ASSERT_WARNING, 0);

    $foo = 10;
    $bar = 11;
    assert('$foo > $bar');
?>
```

Ref:
http://www.hackingwithphp.com/19/8/3/making-assertions

---

**Example from official documentation**

`assert_options` — Set/get the various assert flags

**Example #1 assert_options() example**

```
<?php
// This is our function to handle 
// assert failures
function assert_failure()
{
    echo 'Assert failed';
}

// This is our test function
function test_assert($parameter)
{
    assert(is_bool($parameter));
}

// Set our assert options
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE,   true);
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,     true);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING,  false);
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'assert_failure');

// Make an assert that would fail
test_assert(1);

// This is never reached due to ASSERT_BAIL 
// being true
echo 'Never reached';
?>
```

As per PHP documentation `assert()`

1. If the assertion is given as a string it will be evaluated as PHP code by `assert()`.
2. If you pass a boolean condition as assertion, this condition will not show up as parameter to the assertion function which you may have defined with `assert_options()`.The condition is converted to a string before calling that handler function, and the boolean FALSE is converted as the empty string.
3. `Assertions` should be used as a `debugging` feature only. You may use them for sanity-checks that test for conditions that should always be TRUE and that indicate some programming errors if not or to check for the presence of certain features like extension functions or certain system limits and features.
4. `Assertions` should not be used for normal runtime operations like `input parameter` checks. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated.
5. The behavior of `assert()` may be configured by `assert_options()` or by `.ini-settings` described in that functions manual page.The `assert_options()` function and/or `ASSERT_CALLBACK` configuration directive allow a callback function to be set to handle failed assertions.
   6.`assert()` callbacks are particularly useful for building automated test suites because they allow you to easily capture the code passed to the assertion, along with information on where the assertion was made. While this information can be captured via other methods, using assertions makes it much faster and easier!

Comment: "ASSERT_CALLBACK is a very useful options as it allows you to write an error handler for when your code fails an assertion. It takes the string name of a function to execute when assertions fail [...]"  <-- this is incorrect. The documentation says "Callback to call on failed assertions". This means that `ASSERT_CALLBACK` can take [any callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). This means that you also can pass anonymous functions and anything that can be called like a function.

Answer (score 6):

The [`assert()`](http://php.net/assert) function is a good way to ensure certain conditions are true throughout the life of your code. To quote [this article](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/19/8/3/making-assertions) by Paul Hudson:

> *Essentially, assert() is used to say "This statement must be true - if it isn't, please tell me".*

To enable assertion handling, use `assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE)`, and also use [`assert_options()`](http://PHP.net/assert_options) with other arguments to control what happens when assertions fail (e.g. ending the PHP script execution when an assertion fails, calling a handler function- which could be used to send emails, log data in files and/or database tables, etc.). Refer to the [parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert-options.php#refsect1-function.assert-options-parameters) section for the list of all options and their outcomes.

Try out some of the options in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/Lx7ibhsCpYnJAnkf).

Read [that article](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/19/8/3/making-assertions) for more information about both of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Official Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php):

> Assertions should be used as a debugging feature only.

> As assertions can be configured to be eliminated, they should **not** be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks.

So, I would not use it in production code.