# How to escape DecimalFormat patterns for MessageFormat?

Tags: php, icu

The pattern `}}}}123` is valid syntax in [ICU DecimalFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html), because `}` is in the legal range for a padding character. This can be validated in PHP as follows:

```
$f = new NumberFormatter('en_GB', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL, '*}######0');
$this->assertSame('}}}}123', $f->format(123));
                   -------
                   correct
```

But embedding this in [ICU MessageFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/MessageFormat.html), we have the problem that the brace character ends the argument prematurely and would need escaping.

Again, using PHP to verify that this throws IntlException:

```
$f = new MessageFormatter('en_GB', "{0,number,*}######0}");
$this->assertSame('}}}}123', $f->format([123]));
```

Quoting the format according to ICU MessageFormat syntax doesn't work either, because a quote symbol is an invalid *padChar* in the DecimalFormat grammar. In summary, none of these work:

- `{0,number,*}######0}`
- `{0,number,*'}'######0}`
- `{0,number,'*}######0'}`

It seems that the DecimalFormat syntax is not compatible with MessageFormat's *argStyleText* syntax.

Is this a bug in PHP's Intl extension, or is there a way to escape the decimal pattern in messages?

Please note that this is an academic question about ICU MessageFormat, I am not asking how to pad an integer in PHP.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31122089/454827

Comment: What are you suggesting? My example is not production code, and I am not using PHP's assert function.

Comment: Sorry I think I don't understand your question... maybe you have a problem with last "}", I think you need to open the first "{" to close with the final "}", something like this: ```{{0,number,*}######0}```

Comment: This is not correct and you don't seem to be familiar with ICU MessageFormat syntax