# Trouble extending library in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to extend the Upload library in CodeIgniter. I have been trying all morning, following various tuts and forum posts, but can't get it to work.

If I add the function I want directly into the Upload.php library, it works-- but I know this isn't the right way, and want to do it right since I'm doing it.

Here is the content of the extension [system/application/libraries/MY_Upload.php]:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class MY_Upload extends Upload{
function MY_Upload(){
    parent::Upload();
}
  function mupload($configs,$files){
    if(count($configs) != count($files)){
       return 'array_count_wrong';
    }
$retArr=array();
    for($i=0, $j = count($files);$i<$j;$i++){
        $this->initialize($configs[$i]);
        if(!$this->do_upload($files[$i])){
            array_push($retArr,$this->display_errors());
        }else{
            array_push($retArr,'OK');
        }
    }
    return($retArr);
}
```

?>

And relevant controller code:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$messages=$this->upload->mupload($config,$files);
```

It fails with no indication of why.

What am I doing wrong?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a friggin `}` at the end of the extension

:'(

I REALLY REALLY REALLY wish there was a way to get more informative error messages (or any message at all) when things fail...

Comment: You could enable PHP error reporting (http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) while in a development environment; also, using a good editor or IDE with proper syntax highlighting will help you catch syntax errors like the one you described.

Comment: error reporting is most definitely on. Set to 11, even. I use TextMate (which I lub), but it doesn't seem to highlight blocks, just functions, vars, arrays, etc. It'll blink if you try and put a closing bracket with no matching opening bracket, but doesn't really help when dealing with 10k lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: You might lub another editor, like vim, even better.  vim's static analysis is more powerful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files.

Answer (score 2):

A few extra bits of advice here.

1. You should extend from CI_Upload not Upload
2. You only need to add a contructor with parent::CI_Upload; if you are actually doing something in your controller. Delete function MY_Upload() as you don't need it. :-)

Glad you solved your main problem though!

Comment: Indeedidly. I had the CI_ in there most of the time, but not when I copied the code to paste here. It's in there now :) 

I also deleted the MY_Upload function. Though I'm not clear why... You said "if you're actually doing something in your controller". I think I'm doing stuff in my controller, aren't I? Do you mean calling functions in the parent class directly inside the controller? Thx.

Comment: Sorry replace the word controller with constructor. Basically if you create your own constructor then you need to cal the parents constructor first as when you make a function in the child of an inherited class you are essentially replacing it. If you are not using a constructor in your MY_ class, then you do not need to put an empty constructor in. :-)