# Is there any program that helps you check PHP codes?

Tags: php

Just a curious question but is there any programs that can help/aid you when you write PHP codes? Say there is an error in your code and using this program it would help you locate it, etc.

I might be thinking too much...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't PHP tell you the exact line and file where it encounters an error?

Comment: Are you looking for PHP static analysis? Something like this: http://strategoxt.org/PHP/PhpSat

Comment: BillyONeal, it does. But I was wondering if there was a more detailed and higher level program.

Comment: Err.. what can be more detailed than "Here's what you broke on line X"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a personal preference, I use [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/). Its an integrated development environment for PHP, and comes equipped with syntax as well as error syntax highlighting and a helpful debugger.

Also, with [WAMPserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) installed, I can easily execute my code after editing and run it on my browser, definitely comes in handy.

Comment: @echo: +1, couldn't agree more :)

Answer (score 4):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, pretty much any modern IDE can do this for you. Try these:

- [Netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/)
- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)
- [Aptana](https://web.archive.org/web/20100610101856/http://www.aptana.org:80/php)
- [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)

It will put red squiggly lines (like spellcheck) under errors as you type.

Comment: I use Eclipse PDT, Aptana, and Zend Studio 5.5. If all you care about syntax checking, though, I can scarcely count the number of options available.

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE's (Eclipse PDT has mention, and its my personal preference as well) have some sort of display que for what it thinks is an error. On top of that ther are fulll debuggers like XDebug which you can install that let you set through code a line at a time and set break points and what not.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly use [vim](https://web.archive.org/web/20221228120918/https://www.vim.org/) for editing and I make sure the **php** executable is in my path so I do this for a quick syntax-check on whatever file I have open.

```
:! php -l %
```

If I'm developing on a Windows machine, I install [XAMPP](https://web.archive.org/web/20140121004237/http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) just so I can use the php binary that comes with it.

Comment: I do this as well. Very helpful for a "spell check", as it were.

Answer (score 1):

set error_reporting(E_ALL); (while writing the code, when you have already uploaded your project for public usage, set error_reporting(0);)

It is much easier to find your own mistakes with error_reporting(E_ALL);
You can try two following examples

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
$result = ($value > 0)?'Foo':'Bar';
```

vs

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$result = ($value > 0)?'Foo':'Bar';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run php in lint mode. It will parse the file and report errors, but won't execute any code:

```
php -l file.php
```

Otherwise, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files) has a number of links to static code analysis tools for php.

Answer (score 0):

i use [textmate](https://web.archive.org/web/20221226013441/https://macromates.com/) (on mac) for all my code it has syntax checker for php amongst other things