# PHP: Code checker since PHP is a loose type / dynamic language?

Tags: php, dynamic-languages, weak-typing, loose-typing

I have a small PHP web-based application that is beginning to grow moderately in size.

I'm starting to become concerned with managing my PHP code base, given **PHP** is a **loosely/weak typed, dynamic language**.

How do others manage their code based for loosely/weak typed, dynamic languages?

Do pre-parsers exist for PHP that allow me to runs checks on my code base to identity such things like below?

```
$var1 = 'data';
// vr1 doesn't exist, it's a typo of $var1, but PHP would allow for this and not complain
echo $vr1;
```

**UPDATE**:

The example above might not be the best example but essentially, what I'm trying to convey is that certain errors in a dynamically weak typed language would only be found when the code is run in production at RUN TIME; whereas, some of these issues would typically be found in strongly typed static languages at COMPILE time.

How can I also find these non-algorithm type of errors in PHP prior to moving my code into production without having to create an insane number of Unit Tests?

As such, does anything exist where I can run my PHP code through it, prior to moving into production, and this pre-processor parses my code to ensure I'm only using defined variables, etc.  Essentially, check my code for validation for non-algorithmic type of uses. E.g. not trying perform algebra on a string, etc.

**UPDATE 2**

Please note, this question is still **not answered** because I'm looking for a way to identity these type of non-algorithmic errors in PHP at "compile" type, not RUN TIME.

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language, not a compiled one.

Comment: Honestly PHP is a mess. With includes that can be conditional and these includes themselves can include more files, polluted namespace, and a plethora of other things, it's really hard to know if a variable will be defined or not until runtime.

Comment: @Null That's really a universal problem among programming languages that can conditionally include files, which happens to be an important feature of PHP. It's the job of the programmer to bring structure into his application.

Comment: @Eric The only non-runtime errors PHP can catch are outright syntax errors. Everything else needs to be resolved at runtime. It requires a different programming style than you would apply to something like C. If you can't get used to that, you shouldn't use PHP.

Comment: Downvoted because of the asker's insistence about separating runtime from compile time, even though there is ostensibly no difference between the two in PHP.  Get to know the language you're using before making demands.

Comment: In the spirit of the original question, substitute "code analysis tool" for "compiler".

Comment: @Eric, you won't get any better answer than the one Gordon has already given you.

Answer (score 10):

You can [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) your PHP with `php -l filename.php`. This would show any syntax errors. 
There is IDEs out there that will lint while you write the code. Those usually can also detect issues like shown in your question in addition to linting.

Apart from this, consider [writing UnitTests](http://www.phpunit.de/) for your code to ensure functionality and have a look at http://phpqatools.org for a number of other tools that can assist you in increasing code quality.

Make sure you have `error_reporting(-1);` set during development to enable all errors, in addition to enable `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` in php.ini. Disable the latter two on your production system to prevent exposure of server information.

**Edit after update:** PHP source code is compiled on-the-fly. PHP's *compile time* is effectively *at run time*. If you want compiled PHP, you have to use Facebook's HipHop.

Comment: Writing UnitTest is simple unrealistic. Look at my example above, I'd have to write a unit test for nearly every line of code I have if I were to make a simply variable name typo.

Comment: @Eric It's neither unrealistic nor is it uncommon to write tests for nearly every line of code. A typo will usually break something somewhere. If you have a `function add($var1, $var2) { return $vr1 + $var2; }` it will not pass a UnitTest testing that the input data adds up.

Comment: @Eric Gordon is right. If you haven't started unit testing your PHP code, you should. Right now. Your life will be a lot easier, trust me.

Comment: If you find unit testing to be unrealistic for your code, then that's a problem with your code not with unit testing. The idea is to break your code into distinct functions, with the goal being ones that are referentially transparent (given input a it always returns output b). You can then test that each function does what it's supposed to do. If it does, then either there are no typos or those typos don't effect the behavior of the function.

Answer (score 4):

PHP will definitely complain about that with either a warning or a notice if you set your error_reporting config directive appropriately.

See:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: +1: Doesn't solve all problems, but at least catches some issues like nonexistent variables or undefined indexes.

Comment: My concern though is that it catches these error at RUN TIME (while in production). These error should be catch before the code is in production. These kind of errors would typically be catch in compiled languages at compile time.

Comment: @bearmrider9, please note - my original question is asking for a way to identity these type of non-algorithmic erros at COMPILE time and not RUNTIME. As such, you're answer does not apply.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but isn't php interpreted, rather than compiled like ASP.NET is?

Comment: Yeah, with php COMPILE and RUNTIME are *the same thing* because its an interpreted language.

Answer (score 4):

#### Runtime Errors

Uninitialized variables are **runtime errors** (of level [`E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)) in PHP, so you can only see them at runtime.  The example you gave may or may not end up erroring, depending on how the code is executed.  For instance, it could be that `$vr1` is defined in a conditional `include()` that is sometimes included and sometimes not.

Additionally, it's possible to dynamically create variables at runtime using [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (`$$var`), so again that `$vr1` may actually be defined somewhere.  If the PHP interpreter failed to run valid syntax, or gave compiler errors on valid syntax, that would be a different sort of problem.

You might compare the uninitialized variable circumstance to a divide by zero error.  It's not an error unless it actually happens.

Compiletime errors are [`E_PARSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, or `E_COMPILE_WARNING` (not fatal) in PHP.  These include things like missing files, functions, or classes, i.e. trying to execute code that isn't there—something PHP can't possibly do.  If PHP *may be* able to, it will try.

#### Detection and Prevention

At the very least, you should make sure that your development and testing environments have all of the PHP error junk turned on in the ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL|E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

Or at runtime:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

#### Self Discipline

A few tips for working with PHP that might help:

- Use [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)
- Establish [code smells](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) and write clean syntax
- Do your own type checking (OOP and functional programming can make this easier)
- Avoid the global scope and `include()`-based control structures
- Use an IDE with code awareness aids, like [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).

For instance, in your example above, if you have to pass your variable into a function or method that checks that the parameter [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or `!== null`before using it, you can avoid or mitigate the problem of uninitialized variables.

#### Resources

- [Comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (see Identity, specifically)
- [Type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)
- [`is_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), [`is_float()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php), etc.

Answer (score 0):

That type of error would be caught if you set error reporting to the max.  It would give a Notice indicating that $vr1 wasn't set.

You can set error reporting in your php.ini file, or on individual pages using the ini_set() function.

Comment: But that error would only be found at RUN TIME. How can I get PHP to inform me of that error that $vr1 is not defined at COMPILE time?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is php's lint checker, but that's more of a syntax checker. You can run lint from a command line:

```
php -l path/to/file.php
```

You could build this into your file repository system by setting up a pre-commit check.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is not usually considered to go through a separate COMPILE process perhaps you could explain at what point you consider your code to be COMPILED?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files) that focuses on PHP code analysis tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Hack](http://hacklang.org/) is a statically typed language created by Facebook which is essentially PHP with many features added and removed.
2. [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is an IDE which provides "inspections" which catch many things that would be caught by a static type checker, such as the undefined variable in your example.
3. I started writing a static type checker for PHP [here](https://github.com/jesseschalken/php-type-checker) based on PHP7 type hints and PHPDoc annotations. I never finished it but there are [some passing tests](https://github.com/jesseschalken/php-type-checker/blob/master/src/JesseSchalken/PhpTypeChecker/Test.php) and the design so far seems to be sound.