# Is there something like PyFlakes for PHP?

Tags: php, python, pyflakes

Pretty straight forward question. I'm quite happy with my simple text editor but sometimes it'd be nice to run something like [PyFlakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) on my code before running to check for any obvious errors like undeclared variables or syntax errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a static code analyzer \[like Lint\] for PHP files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run this:

```
 php -l filename
```

Comment: Not exactly - no warnings for undeclared variables, no warnings for using "+" with strings (which php idiotically turns to 0),  it seems to do just what it says in man php - "Syntax check only (lint)"

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is wrong - the question is neither a duplicated nor does the given command do what "pyflakes" does.

"pyflakes" is a python project that integrates with Vim, and allows you to check for interpreter errors in your python code live (as you are coding).

However, i am not aware of any existing vim extension which replicates the functionality of pyflakes for PHP code.

Comment: Umm, Orbit gave me just the answer I was looking for, so, no, I wouldn't say it's wrong. I was not asking about the specific vim plugin – I actually use the command line version.