# Is there a simple way of setting breakpoints and debug PHP scripts locally in the command line?

Tags: php, debugging, command-line, local

I don't know if there is a tool like this for PHP, but I've been using gdb for C lately with great success. I want to be able to set breakpoints and execute a PHP script, then stepping through my functions to check what's going on.

Can this be done with PHP?

If so I'd love some links to tutorials or other resources. I found nothing while Googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the command line there is an excellent tool called **[phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/)**:

> ### Features
>
> - Stepthrough Debugging
> - Flexible Breakpoints (Class Method, Function, File:Line, Address,    Opcode)
> - Easy Access to PHP with built-in eval()
> - Easy Access to Currently Executing Code
> - Userland API
> - SAPI Agnostic - Easily Integrated
> - PHP Configuration File Support
> - JIT Super Globals - Set Your Own !!
> - Optional readline Support - Comfortable Terminal Operation
> - Remote Debugging Support - Bundled Java GUI

Answer (score 1):

See here for some tools:

[xDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6379

xDebug certainly provides the ability to set breakpoints.

[*source*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)

[Tool for PHP code analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156157/tool-for-php-code-analysis/4156265#4156265)

Comment: Voting this one down. Question specifies **local** debugging using a **command line tool**. Most of your links are about **remote** debugging using **eclipse** from windows. The other links open for such a load of information that I don't even know where to start. Not a very good answer at all. I've already found xDebug, but it seems more like a PHP module for remote debugging than a tool used for local debugging.