# php, how to determine how much of code has been ran?

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to log what lines per file was run in php. Xdebug can do that, thats all I know. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want a code analyzer,  here is a good [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379471/63678) about this