# Check for PHP Syntax errors?

Tags: php, syntax-error, token

Well, I have run into a bit of a pickle here.  I am needing to check some PHP for syntax errors.  I noticed this bit that needs to run from the commandline:

`php -l somefile.php`

However, is there a way to run this from within a PHP file itself?  I've been looking and have think that I can use `parse_str` function somehow to accomplish this by entering it into a $_GET, but can't quite understand how this works.

Someone else told me to use `token_get_all()` php function to determine this.

But I can't figure out how to do this with any approach?  Can anyone here give me some sample code to get started perhaps??  I don't think using `eval()` is the way to go, although I had an `eval($code)` working, but don't think I should run the script if there are PHP syntax errors.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, as always!

Comment: Why not spawn a `php -l` subprocess?

Comment: @arxanas - How can this be done??  Possible answer...?

Comment: @SolomonClosson, I think he's terse comment is referring to http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 6):

You could simply do `shell_exec()` like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('php -l /path/to/filename.php');
```

This gives you the output of the command line operation in the string `$output`.

Comment: Ok, have fixed the undefined output error, however, now it returns an empty string regardless if there are PHP Syntax errors or not.

Comment: Using exec() instead of shell_exec() will give you the output in the third parameter:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 5):

I use `token_get_all` for this. I have some PHP code in the db. Before saving, I do

```
function is_valid_php_code_or_throw( $code ) {
        $old = ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        try {
                token_get_all("<?php\n$code", TOKEN_PARSE);
        }
        catch ( Throwable $ex ) {
                $error = $ex->getMessage();
                $line = $ex->getLine() - 1;
                throw new InvalidInputException("PARSE ERROR on line $line:\n\n$error");
        }
        finally {
                ini_set('display_errors', $old);
        }
}
```

Works like a charm. Syntax only. No missing variables, type incompayibility etc.

`InvalidInputException` is my own. You can make it anything, or return a bool, or handle the exception yourself.

I'm not sure if `display_errors` is necessary. It was at some point.

Comment: This string parses but crashes if your try to run it `<?php class {CLASS}`:

https://3v4l.org/p9k1Y

Comment: Eh. That's weird. But you should add the `TOKEN_PARSE` flag: https://3v4l.org/VFDrG

Answer (score 4):

It is safer to check the return status of `php -l`

```
$fileName = '/path/to/file.php';
exec("php -l {$fileName}", $output, $return);

if ($return === 0) {
    // Correct syntax
} else {
    // Syntax errors
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://www.tehplayground.com/026v6OSCW8y1eakr) to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$php_file = 'The path to your file';
if(substr(`php -l $php_file`, 0, 16) == 'No syntax errors') {
    // Correct syntax
} else {
    // Error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[php_check_syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php) should do the trick. If you're running PHP >= 5.05, see the first comment in the comments section for the implementation.

Comment: This function was removed from PHP... [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php)

Comment: Good catch @SolomonClosson. OP, luckily in the comments is an implementation that you can use. I won't paste it here as it's very large, but it's the top comment.

Comment: This is a PHP4 function and has been removed in PHP 5.0.x. Moreover it was basically just an alias to `eval()` - it just ran the supplied code to detect parsing errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `exec` to check for syntax errors.

```
$tempFile = path/of/file
$syntaxParseError = strpos(exec('php -l '.$tempFile), 'No syntax errors detected') === false;`
```

Unfortunately, this will not give you the line number or tell you anything about the error. For that you will either need to install static analyzer on your server [Is there a static code analyzer [like Lint] for PHP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) or write your own parser.

NB. `token_get_all()` will not determine anything on its own, but it useful function for making a parser.

Answer (score -2):

Why use the shell at all?

```
function syntax_is_valid($code)
{
    try
    {
        @eval($code);
    }
    catch (ParseError $e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Alternatively use `$e->getMessage()` for more info.

Comment: How do you prevent all the side effects from running (evaling) the code? Such as printing, connecting to the database, writing files, etc.